# How to convert string to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, binary

I am in need of a way to get the binary representation of a string in python. e.g.

```
st = "hello world"
toBinary(st)
```

Is there a module of some neat way of doing this?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be, specifically?

Comment: By "binary", do you mean 0101010 type or the `ord`inal number of each character in (e.g. hex)?

Comment: Assuming that you actually mean binary (zeros and ones), do you want a binary representation of each character (8 bits per character) one after another? e.g. h is ascii value 104 would be 01101000 in binary

Comment: This question has been answered many times on stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599226/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-ascii-string-in-python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553310/python-2-5-convert-string-to-binary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Binary to ASCII and vice versa (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa-python)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> st = "hello world"
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)
'1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'

#using `bytearray`
>>> ' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(st, 'utf-8'))
'1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'
```

Comment: Or if you want each binary number to be 1 byte: ' '.join(format(ord(i),'b').zfill(8) for i in st)

Comment: For full bytes you can also use `' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)`, which is about 35% faster than the `zfill(8)` solution (at least on my machine).

Comment: What about converting more-than-one-byte chars, like `β`, e.g., which    seems to me represented by `11001110 10110010` internally?

Comment: I know this was posted long time ago, but what about non-ASCII characters?

Comment: **Format Specification Mini-Language**: `'  '.join('{:08b}'.format(d) for d in bytearray('ß', 'utf-8'))`, output: `'11000011 10011111'`, try other encoding `utf-16`, `utf-32` for **non-ASCII**.

Comment: Is there a way to reconstruct the original string from the bytearray one: 1101000 1100101 1101100 '?

Comment: Which is the reverse operation?

Answer (score 123):

If by binary you mean `bytes` type, you can just use [`encode` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) of the string object that encodes your string as a bytes object using the passed encoding type. You just need to make sure you pass a proper encoding to `encode` function.

```
In [9]: "hello world".encode('ascii')                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[9]: b'hello world'

In [10]: byte_obj = "hello world".encode('ascii')                                                                                                                                                           

In [11]: byte_obj                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[11]: b'hello world'

In [12]: byte_obj[0]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[12]: 104
```

Otherwise, if you want them in form of zeros and ones --binary representation-- as a more pythonic way you can first convert your string to byte array then use `bin` function within `map` :

```
>>> st = "hello world"
>>> map(bin,bytearray(st))
['0b1101000', '0b1100101', '0b1101100', '0b1101100', '0b1101111', '0b100000', '0b1110111', '0b1101111', '0b1110010', '0b1101100', '0b1100100']
```

Or you can join it:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(st)))
'0b1101000 0b1100101 0b1101100 0b1101100 0b1101111 0b100000 0b1110111 0b1101111 0b1110010 0b1101100 0b1100100'
```

Note that in *python3* you need to specify an encoding for `bytearray` function :

```
>>> ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(st,'utf8')))
'0b1101000 0b1100101 0b1101100 0b1101100 0b1101111 0b100000 0b1110111 0b1101111 0b1110010 0b1101100 0b1100100'
```

You can also use `binascii` module in python 2:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> bin(int(binascii.hexlify(st),16))
'0b110100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000111011101101111011100100110110001100100'
```

`hexlify` return the hexadecimal representation of the binary data then you can convert to int by specifying 16 as its base then convert it to binary with `bin`.

Comment: Not only this is more pythonic, but this is "more" correct for multi-byte non-ASCII strings.

Comment: Just to note that (at least for the current version `3.7.4`): (1) `bytearray` expects an encoding (not just a string) and (2) `map(bin, ...)` will return the `map` object.  For the first point, I use for instance `bob`.encoding('ascii')` as suggested by @Tao. For the second, point, using the `join` method, as in the other examples of @Kasramvd will display the desired result.

Comment: the "hello world".encode('ascii') is perfect

Comment: This is odd. In python3, I can do `>>> bin(bytearray("g", 'utf8')[0]) # '0b1100111'`. But, I cannot do `>>> bin("g".encode("utf8"))`

Answer (score 54):

We just need to encode it.

```
'string'.encode('ascii')
```

Comment: For me (`v3.7.4`), this returns a `bytes` object (with the ascii representations of each byte, if available), and in order to display its binary representation, I need `bin`, e.g. with `' '.join(item[2:] for item in map(bin, 'bob'.encode('ascii')))` (note that `0b` needs to be removed at the beginning of the binary representation of each character).

Answer (score 16):

You can access the code values for the characters in your string using the `ord()` built-in function.  If you then need to format this in binary, the `string.format()` method will do the job.

```
a = "test"
print(' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in a))
```

(Thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary for posting that code snippet.)

While the above code works in Python 3, this matter gets more complicated if you're assuming any encoding other than UTF-8.  In Python 2, strings are byte sequences, and ASCII encoding is assumed by default.  In Python 3, strings are assumed to be Unicode, and there's a separate `bytes` type that acts more like a Python 2 string.  If you wish to assume any encoding other than UTF-8, you'll need to specify the encoding.

In Python 3, then, you can do something like this:

```
a = "test"
a_bytes = bytes(a, "ascii")
print(' '.join(["{0:b}".format(x) for x in a_bytes]))
```

The differences between UTF-8 and ascii encoding won't be obvious for simple alphanumeric strings, but will become important if you're processing text that includes characters not in the ascii character set.

Answer (score 9):

In Python version 3.6 and above you can use [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) to format result.

```
str = "hello world"
print(" ".join(f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in str))

01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100
```

- The left side of the colon, ord(i), is the actual object whose value
  will be formatted and inserted into the output. Using ord() gives you
  the base-10 code point for a single str character.
- The right hand side of the colon is the format specifier. 08 means
  width 8, 0 padded, and the b functions as a sign to output the
  resulting number in base 2 (binary).

Comment: Note that you are overriding ```str```

Answer (score 3):

```
def method_a(sample_string):
    binary = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in sample_string)

def method_b(sample_string):
    binary = ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(sample_string,encoding='utf-8')))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from timeit import timeit

    sample_string = 'Convert this ascii strong to binary.'

    print(
        timeit(f'method_a("{sample_string}")',setup='from __main__ import method_a'),
        timeit(f'method_b("{sample_string}")',setup='from __main__ import method_b')
    )

# 9.564299999998184 2.943955828988692
```

method_b is substantially more efficient at converting to a byte array because it makes low level function calls instead of manually transforming every character to an integer, and then converting that integer into its binary value.

Answer (score 2):

This is an update for the existing answers which used [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) and can not work that way anymore:

```
>>> st = "hello world"
>>> map(bin, bytearray(st))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Because, as explained in the link above, if the source is a string,  *you must also give the encoding*:

```
>>> map(bin, bytearray(st, encoding='utf-8'))
<map object at 0x7f14dfb1ff28>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(format(i, 'b') for i in bytearray(str, encoding='utf-8'))
```

> This works okay since its easy to now revert back to the string as no
> zeros will be added to reach the 8 bits to form a byte hence easy to
> revert to string to avoid complexity of removing the zeros added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison of bit lengths in various [encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) of [ASCII](https://www.ascii-code.com/) 127 (delete). Note the respective 24, 16, and 32 bit [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in UTF-8-SIG, UTF-16, and UTF-32:

```py
>>> for encoding in ('utf-8', 'utf-8-sig', 'utf-16', 'utf-16-le', 'utf-16-be', 'utf-32', 'utf-32-le', 'utf-32-be'): print(''.join(' '.join((f'{encoding:9}', f'{len(bs):2}', bs)) for bs in [''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in '\x7f'.encode(encoding))]))
...
utf-8      8 01111111
utf-8-sig 32 11101111101110111011111101111111
utf-16    32 11111111111111100111111100000000
utf-16-le 16 0111111100000000
utf-16-be 16 0000000001111111
utf-32    64 1111111111111110000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000
utf-32-le 32 01111111000000000000000000000000
utf-32-be 32 00000000000000000000000001111111
```

Answer (score -2):

```
a = list(input("Enter a string\t: "))
def fun(a):
    c =' '.join(['0'*(8-len(bin(ord(i))[2:]))+(bin(ord(i))[2:]) for i in a])
    return c
print(fun(a))
```

Comment: Would you like to augment this unreadable code-only answer with some explanation? That would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. In case you want to improve readability, try the info provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help