# Decode a base64 string to a decimal string

Tags: python, string, encoding, base64

I have a string say `FhY=` which has been encoded to hex. So when run

```
>>> b6 = 'FhY='
>>> b6.decode('base64')
'\x16\x16'
```

This is a hex string that once converted should be `22 22`. This result has been proven on the site https://conv.darkbyte.ru/. However, I cannot seem to do a proper conversion from base64 to decimal representation. Some of the challenges I am facing are

1. Expectation of decimal being an int. I just want base 10
2. Incorrect values. I have tried the following conversions `base64 > base16`([Convert a base64 encoded string to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010277/convert-a-base64-encoded-string-to-binary)), `base64 >  binary > decimal`([Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)) both of which have failed.

Please assist.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using `struct`?

Comment: I have not had a look at it. Let me do so now

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams probably because he needs an example :P `struct.unpack('H','\x16\x16')` maybe?

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley. seems to work. However is there a solution that does not involve a two step process? One straight from base64 to base10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert each byte from the decoded string to its decimal value. So this should solve it:

```py
b6 = 'FhY='
' '.join([ str(ord(c)) for c in b6.decode('base64') ])
```

Results in `22 22`

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Is this function reversible? How could I map the resulting base-10 text back to the base-64 string?

Comment: @Leonid you can reverse the function by using ```''.join(map(lambda x: chr(int(x)), '22 22'.split())).encode('base64')```