# Base64 Binary String representation to float convertion

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, binary, base64

I did a lot of research and can't seem to find the answer for this, e.g:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010277/convert-a-base64-encoded-string-to-binary)

So I have this base64 encoded string: `BzM=`, and I know that the correct value is `18.43`

This value comes from a decimal field from a MySql database with the following associated definition `{'scale': '2', 'decimal.precision': '8'}`, so it's `DECIMAL(8,2)`.

The implementation in Java:

```
String encoded = "BzM=";
int scale = 2; // comes from definition above associated with the field
final BigDecimal decoded = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded)), scale);
System.out.println("RES: " + decoded); // RES: 18.43
```

[Working example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/lMhX40)

I'm almost sure that there's an 'easy' way for doing this with Python as well, I searched a lot and couldn't find anything helpful (I may have searched the wrong way).

I tried to reverse engineer this, with no success (can't find where the scale arg enters also):

```
import base64, struct
x = base64.encodebytes(struct.pack('!f', 18.43))
print(x) # b'QZNwpA==\n' SHOULD BE BzM=
```

So, I need to simply translate this Java implementation into Python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`base64.b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) to decode the string, then convert the result byte-string to an int using [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes), finally dividing by `10**scale` to get the required result:

```
import base64

enc = 'BzM='
bytes = base64.b64decode(enc)
scale = 2
num = int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder='big') / 10 ** scale
print(num)
```

Output:

```
18.43
```

Out of interest, the reverse coding would be:

```
base64.b64encode(int.to_bytes(1843, length=int(math.log2(1843))//8+1, byteorder='big'))
```

Comment: Wow, that was 'easy'/quick. Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you know the `byteorder='big'`, it's just convention or it implied some try/error?

Comment: @ManuelSimões it was an educated guess :)

Comment: Really Nice. Have a good day Sir

Comment: @ManuelSimões thanks - you too. Note I've added the encoding logic to the answer as well just for interest.