# Represent a hash string to binary in Python

Tags: python, string, hash, binary

Consider the following image:

[image]

How can I represent hashcode to binary format (as 0110011)

Thank you

Comment: Since hashcode is str, this is possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[*Originally answered by @Ashwini Chaudhary*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18815890/3905567)

```
''.join(format(ord(n),'b') for n in hashcode)
'11001001100001101111101111100110110010110100110100110010011001011100110111000110000111011111000011001011101011100101110000111011111010111100011000101100100111000110011110101110010110011011000111100100111000'
```

#### Another update

Much cleaner approach from @m.wasowski, I am combining his idea to try and solve this (still not sure if this is what exactly OP wants, since lengths of words in sentence are not consistent):

```
def text_to_bin(text, n_bin=16):
    if n_bin < 16 or n_bin > 36:
        print "n_bin must be >= 16 and <= 36"
    else:
        for word in text.split():
            word_ord = ['{}'.format(bin(int(hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest(), n_bin)))]
            print '{} {}'.format(word, ''.join(word_ord)[2:])

text_to_bin('A cat in the woods', 16)
A 1111111110001010110001001110000111001111010011100001111101010000001101001011001001101011011011100101110101011001011111000101001
cat 11010000011101111111001001000100110111101111100010100111000011100101111010100111010110001011110110000011010100101111110011011000
in 10011101101011011111111101001011011110011111000101111111001000001000111001001111101100110111101001010010110000010101011011111
the 10001111110001000010110001101101110111111001100101100110110110110011101100001001111010000100001101100101000000110100001101010111
woods 10110111101111111011100101001001001001111100010000000101011101111100000100000001100111100000000010000100110101110011001010010111
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to get a fixed length of hash values for each word in a string? For example "A cat in the woods". I would like to get a hash value of each word (in binary representation)

Comment: Is it possible the results from the MD5 ,for each word, to be of fixed length in the form of '100011...'?

Comment: @PanosTheo, what do you exactly mean? you want to have fixed length of '100011', like 8b => '00100011'?

Comment: What I really want is to create a b-bit binary hash for every word in ,lets say, the above string. What I want to do, in the end, is to make a simhash algorithm so I need the b-bit binary hashes of the words to begin with. (Thank you for bearing with me. I know my English is bad)

Comment: Have you read comment from @m.wasowski? I will update the answer with his idea, much cleaner

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> s="cat"
>>> hashcode=hashlib.md5(s).hexdigest()
>>> bin(int(hashcode,16))
'0b11010000011101111111001001000100110111101111100010100111000011100101111010100111010110001011110110000011010100101111110011011000'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bin() function

```
bin(d077ff) # Result: '0b11...'
```

to remove 0b you can do this:

```
int(str(temp)[2:])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the bin() function cannot be used with the above string and it will produce results of uneven length. For example "cat" and "bird" will produce binary with different length. How can I have a fixed length of the result? I hope I was clear. Thanks

Comment: why can't bin be used? 
and of course cat and bird will have different length in binary. I am confused what you mean by that.

Comment: What I want is to represent each string with a fixed length of a hash value in the form of '0011100011'

Comment: that near impossible to do unless your strings are going to fixed length?

Comment: Is there a way to represent k-bit hash values for each word in a string?Using Adler32 or MD5 algorithms,does the job but the format is not in the form of '100001..'. Is there a way to produce the hash values to this format?

Comment: hashes are displayed as hexadecimal, so you can use `bin(int('998fd550322', 16))`

Comment: @m.wasowski, great call with `int`, I'd love to update my answer using your idea, much cleaner

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This approach produces binary hash values with different lengths. I need the hash values to be of fixed length (for example 32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but try this:

```
binhashcode = ''.join(bin(int(i,16)).zfill(4) for i in hashcode)
```