# Converting ASCII to Binary files on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, matlab, binary, ascii

I have files containing floating point numbers in ascii format that I need to convert to binary (.bin) format on a Mac 10.10.3.  I am most familiar with Matlab but alternatively could use python or C.  I found a program called Ascii converter 1.0 (Mac) written in java but got errors about a nonexistent package when I tried to compile it.  It did not come with any associated documentation that would help me to compile and run it properly.  I did some google searching but have so far not found a better alternative.

Is there a simple code that would take an input file (vmodel.txt) and output a binary file (vmodel.bin)?  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to binary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: What format do you want the output to be in?  Do you want IEEE754?  Single-precision or double-precision?

Comment: double-precision.  However I found a working code in the distribution of seismic unix (a2b.c) which did the job

Comment: doru, I saw the post on "Convert string to binary in python", but in this case I did not want a file with the numbers converted to binary (ascii binary with 0's and 1's) but a binary formatted file. Converting the numbers themselves to binary is straightfoward, changing the file format proved to be different