# Cannot find error trying to convert zipcode to binary

Tags: python, string, if-statement, barcode, zipcode

Here is my code I feel like this should be working. I added the zipcode = str(zipcode) just now to see if it would work which it didnt so I will probably take that out and just have the original zipcode be a string. I need it to be a string because I dont want the binary numbers to actually add to eachother. When I initialize the function in the python shell it just returns nothing

```
def digitConvert(zipcode):
zipcode = str(zipcode)
n = 0
binary = ""
while n < len(zipcode):
    if zipcode[n] == 0:
        binary = binary + "11000"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 1:
        binary = binary + "00011"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 2:
        binary = binary + "00101"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 3:
        binary = binary + "00110"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 4:
        binary = binary + "01001"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 5:
        binary = binary + "01010"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 6:
        binary = binary + "01100"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 7:
        binary = binary + "10001"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 8:
        binary = binary + "10010"
        n = n + 1
    elif zipcode[n] == 9:
        binary = binary + "10100"
        n = n + 1
return binary
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python

Comment: I think there is a problem with your spacing in python.....

Comment: If you do `str(zipcode)`, the elements you get by `zipcode[n]` will be characters, not numbers. So something like `if zipcode[n] == '0'` would work better.

Comment: this doesnt really help me at all. The final result isnt going to be the binary the binary is going to be used to drawn a barcode with turtle graphics

Comment: You have to indent the body of the function.

Comment: DRY: Do `n = n + 1` outside the `if` statement, instead of repeating it for each case.

Comment: You could also use a dictionary to map characters to binary strings, instead of all those `if/elif` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the zip code is an integer. Here is a little python function that converts an integer to binary. Default is you want 24 bits of binary.

```
def int2bin(n, count=24):
    """returns the binary of integer n, using count number of digits"""
    return "".join([str((n >> y) & 1) for y in range(count-1, -1, -1)])
```

For example, my zip code is 60517 so I would do this:

```
>>> print int2bin(60517)  
000000001110110001100101
```

If I only want 16 binary bits:

```
>>> print int2bin(60517, 16)
1110110001100101
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `zipcode[n]` is a character, not a number, so it will never compare equal to numbers (Python doesn't convert them automatically). There are also a number of simplifications you can make, such as using a `for` loop instead of indexing the string, and using a dictionary to map from decimal digits to binary strings.

```
def digitConvert(zipcode):
    zipcode = str(zipcode)
    digitMap = { '0': '11000', '1': '00011', '2': '00101', ... }
    binary = ""
    for digit in zipcode:
        if digit in digitMap:
            binary += digitMap[digit]
    return binary
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem with your code... other than the indents and checking the `if` conditions.

```
def digitConvert(zipcode):
    zipcode = str(zipcode)
    n = 0
    binary = ""
    while n < len(zipcode):
        if zipcode[n] == '0':
            binary = binary + "11000"
        elif zipcode[n] == '1':
            binary = binary + "00011"
        elif zipcode[n] == '2':
            binary = binary + "00101"
        elif zipcode[n] == '3':
            binary = binary + "00110"
        elif zipcode[n] == '4':
            binary = binary + "01001"
        elif zipcode[n] == '5':
            binary = binary + "01010"
        elif zipcode[n] == '6':
            binary = binary + "01100"
        elif zipcode[n] == '7':
            binary = binary + "10001"
        elif zipcode[n] == '8':
            binary = binary + "10010"
        elif zipcode[n] == '9':
            binary = binary + "10100"
        n = n + 1
    return binary
```

Update:

You can simplify the entire thing to this :

```
def digitConvert(zipcode):
  zipcode = str(zipcode)
  x = { 
    "0" : "11000",
    "1" : "00011",
    "2" : "00101",
    "3" : "00110",
    "4" : "01001",
    "5" : "01010",
    "6" : "01100",
    "7" : "10001",
    "8" : "10010",
    "9" : "10100"
  }
  return "".join(x[i] for i in zipcode if i in x)
```