# How to print bytes and bits in python

Tags: python, byte

I am writing a Skype-like program. Obviously, I need to encrypt every single message before it is sent to the server, but in order to do that, I need it to be translated into machine code. But do I do that in Python? When I try to use encode, all I get is "b' the string I have encoded'". But what I need would be **'00000001 00000010 ...'** so that I can work with machine code directly for better encryption. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
st = 'Plain string'
l = list(st)
t = ''
for x in l:
   t+= format(ord(x),'b')
print(t)
```