# How to replace user's input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a *Text to Binary* converter script. Here's what I've got..

```
userInput = input()
a = ('00000001')
b = ('00000010')
#...Here I have every remaining letter translated in binary.
z = ('00011010')
```

So let's say the user types the word "Tree", I want to convert every letter in binary and display it. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do here.
PS. I'm a bit newbie! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have attempted to solve the problem isn't ideal. You've backed yourself into a corner by assigning the binary values to variables.

With variables, you are going to have to use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to dynamically get their value:

```
result = ' '.join((eval(character)) for character in myString)
```

Be advised however, the general consensus regarding the use of `eval()` and similar functions is **don't**. A much better solution would be to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to map the binary values, instead of using variables:

```
characters = { "a" : '00000001', "b" :'00000010' } #etc

result = ' '.join(characters[character] for character in myString)
```

The ideal solution however, would be to use the built-in [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function:

```
result = ' '.join(format(ord(character), 'b') for character in myString)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a dictionary is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Check the [ord](http://www.linuxnix.com/pfotd-python-ord-function-examples/) function:

```
userinput = input()
binaries = [ord(letter) for letter in userinput]
```

Answer (score 0):

cheeky one-liner that prints each character on a new line with label

```
[print(val, "= ", format(ord(val), 'b')) for val in input()]
#this returns a list of "None" for each print statement
```

similarly cheeky one-liner to print with arbitrary seperator specified by print's sep value:

```
print(*[str(val) + "= "+str(format(ord(val), 'b')) for val in input()], sep = ' ')
```

Copy and paste into your favorite interpreter :)