# Save txt file as binary in python

Tags: python, file, controller, odoo

How do I generate a txt file that will be saved as binary file.
it is said that it is needed to be a binary to call the file in  web controller(odoo)

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python

Answer (score 4):

```
# read textfile into string 
with open('mytxtfile.txt', 'r') as txtfile:
    mytextstring = txtfile.read()

# change text into a binary array
binarray = ' '.join(format(ch, 'b') for ch in bytearray(mytextstring))

# save the file
with open('binfileName', 'br+') as binfile:
    binfile.write(binarray)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a task where I needed a file with text data in binary mode. No 1s and 0s, just data 'in binary mode to obtain a bytes object.'

When I tried the suggestion above, with `binarray = ' '.join(format(ch, 'b') for ch in bytearray(mytextstring))`, even after specifying the mandatory `encoding=` for `bytearray()`, I got an error saying that `binarray` was a string, so it could not be written in binary format (using the `'wb'` or `'br+'` modes for `open()`).

Then I went to the Python bible and read:

> bytearray() then converts the string to bytes using `str.encode()`.

So I noticed that all I really needed was `str.encode()` to get a byte object. Problem solved!

```py
filename = "/path/to/file/filename.txt"

# read file as string:
f = open(filename, 'r')
mytext = f.read()

# change text into binary mode:
binarytxt = str.encode(mytext)

# save the bytes object
with open('filename_bytes.txt', 'wb') as fbinary:
    fbinary.write(binarytxt)
```