# Python : special char to binary

Tags: python, binary, special-characters

I'm using the answer i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python).

My function is

```
def to_bin(s):
    return ' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(s))
```

It was working really well until i tried to convert a '%' character, i get the output :

```
>>>to_bin('%')
'100101'
```

while my expected result is :

```
>>>to_bin('%')
'0100101'
```

Do any of you have a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your format specifier to pad with zeros to seven characters:

```
def to_bin(s): 
    return ' '.join(format(x, '07b') for x in bytearray(s))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i realise now how stupid was my question.

Comment: @AntoineLB, For me it's a new information. So it's not a stupid question.