# How to handle and convert different bases in Python without parsing them into Strings?

Tags: python, binary, hex, decimal

I have a number in hex that I need to convert into binary, to be able to perform bitwise operations on it. The problems is that all the functions I found that convert numbers into binary - like format() - return strings, but I need the number  in a data type that can be manipulated like binary.

Found fomrat(), but that returns Strings. I found int(), which can turn it into an integer, but can't find an equivalent for binary.

What I'm trying to do is for example: add 1 to 0b0001 and get the sum as 0b0010 and I did not find a way of doing it when 0b0001 is a String.

Comment: Can you clarify "a number in hex"? If your value is already an integer then you can simply perform bitwise operations on it as per usual.

Comment: i think; this might be the same proble as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python

Comment: @Chathan Driehuys sure, I have added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how you input an integer, Python treats it the same. That means you can do math exactly how you expect. For example:

```
hex_num = 0xff

# We can show its binary equivalent
format(hex_num, 'b')

# We can also do math with it
result = hex_num + 1
# including bitwise operations
result2 = hex_num << 1
```

You can then output the result in any format you want using functions like `format` or `bin` that you have already found. The key is that there is no difference internally between a "hex number", a "binary number", or a normal integer.