# Python: Read a text file and write it as a binary file

Tags: python, buffer, binaryfiles

I have a text input file with the following content:

input.feature

```
3   0   1   1   193:1 225:1
2   0   1   1   57:1 1005:1
4   0   1   1   467:1 7:1
5   0   1   1   619:1 259:1
```

I want to convert it to a binary `buffer` file. This is my attempt using Python:

```
in_file = open('input.feature', 'r', buffering=1000)
out_file = io.open('output.buffer', 'wb')

out_byte_array = bytearray(in_file.read())
out_file.write(out_byte_array)
out_file.close()
```

The output file I get is not a binary file, it's a text file with the same content as input file. What am I doing wrong? I also tried using `BytesIO` but I couldn't figure out how to write bytesIO content to a binary file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A binary file writer 'wb' writes the data into the file byte by byte. You will able to see the data in output file because the characters in it written byte by byte not in the form of bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: @CorentinLimier He wants to write the one file's text data into other file into the form of bytes using binary writer 'wb'.