# Convert a long string made of digits into a long binary string

Tags: python, binary

Let's say I've the following `str`:

```
x = '321638153513213851313516841513153168135132513151351468464513513216516816816846541351351351516168135135168746513212313516354654684468463513213513581'
```

And so on...

I d'like to convert it to binary, how can I do ?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python) and there is also duplicates of it. The difference is that my string is in fact a very long number, not a sentence of made of chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the bin command for something like this?

```
x = 321638153513213851313516841513153168135132513151351468464513513216516816816846541351351351516168135135168746513212313516354654684468463513213513581
b = bin(x)
print(b)
```

To get your string to be an integer, you can first convert it using `int()`:

```
x = int(x)
# Convert to binary...
```