# correct convert string to bynary python

Tags: python, string, binary

I have a string I need to convert into a binary. I tried this:

```
bin = ''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in strr)
```

But the result is the wrong length, because Python doesn't keep leading zeros.  For instance instead of `01110100` it outputs `1110100`.

This method:

```
temp = '{0:08b}'.format(frame)
```

doesn't work with strings.

How can I convert a string to binary correctly?

EDIT:

Sample Input: `'test'`

Desired Output: `'1110100011001010111001101110100'`

Comment: What is "binary view" supposed to mean?

Comment: What is your expect output for input `'74 65 73 74' `?

Comment: binary view - 0 an 1. Hex view (74 65 73 74) might be unwanted in my question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that, @BurhanKhalid. OP here already knows how to format as binary: the question seems to be how to format as zero-padded 8-bit strings.

Comment: try this test=74657374
bin(test)[2:]

Comment: @Ajay, thank you for your help, Adam Smith has already helped me. By the way, your method also has the same problem: the result of bin(74) will be '0b1001010', but the correct output is '0b01001010'

Comment: There are [any](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18815820/113632) [number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8553310/113632) of [existing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11599226/113632) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/113632) covering this (including the zero padding requirement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is doing what you need it to do. How about this instead:

```
''.join("{:08b}".format(int(num, 16)) for num in strr.split())
```

DEMO

```
In [34]: strr
Out[34]: '74 65 73 74'

In [35]: ''.join("{:08b}".format(int(num, 16)) for num in strr.split())
Out[35]: '01110100011001010111001101110100'
```

If your text is REALLY ordinal-encoded hex, then you've got a really funky way of storing data but you could do:

```
''.join("{:08b}".format(ord(num)) for num in strr
```

DEMO

```
In [42]: strr
Out[42]: '74 65 73 74'

In [43]: ''.join("{:08b}".format(ord(num)) for num in strr)
Out[43]: '0011011100110100001000000011011000110101001000000011011100110011001000000011011100110100'
```