# In Python, read chunks of a file as decimal numbers

Tags: python, file, decimal, bit-manipulation

My input files could be arbitrary, and so I will use

```
f = open("in-file", 'rb')
```

The chunk size is about 4K Bytes, and so I will use

```
f.read(4096)
```

What I want to do is to read chunks by chunks from the file.
Moreover, as chunk is actually a $2^15$-bit (4KB) sequence, when reading a chunk, I need to transform it into a decimal value for further computation.

For example, if the first chunk is of form 0000...10, what I want is having another variable keeping the corresponding decimal value, eg., x=2.

From [Convert string to list of bits and viceversa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237926/convert-string-to-list-of-bits-and-viceversa) I know that its code can help me read chunks by chunks.

```
def tobits(s):
    result = []
    for c in s:
        bits = bin(ord(c))[2:]
        bits = '00000000'[len(bits):] + bits
        result.extend([int(b) for b in bits])
    return result
```

However, I don't know how to transform the output list into decimal value. Could someone give me some sample code? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: Is the "chunk" a bunch of bytes that you want the numeric value of? Or is it text, that is, a number written in base 2 using the characters `1` and `0`?

Comment: (Understand that there is usually no such thing as a "decimal" number in a program's memory, it's all some sort of binary representation.)

Comment: yes, chunks are a sequence of bits of a file. For example, if chunk size is set to be 2, and if a file happens to be of form 10010100, then this file has 4 chunks, which are 00, 01, 01, 10.

Comment: Is `int('10010100', 2)` what you're looking for? The `2` means from base 2 (i.e. binary).

Comment: @user4478 What I was really asking was whether when you say that the file contains 01000001, are you saying that when opened in a text editor, I'd see an `A`, and not the string `01000001`. (It might seem a silly question, but the word "binary representation" is ambiguous enough to cause confusion.)

Comment: The file could be arbitrary (the file format is unknown), and so in my question, if the first chunk happens to be 01000001, it has no guarantee that 'A' is shown if a text editor is used. This is because probably the first chunk could be some header or something else but not the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you want something like the following:

```
def bytes_to_long(bytes):
    result = 0l
    for c in bytes:
        result *= 256
        result += ord(c)
    return result
```

That said, it's likely this is going to be somewhat slow, 4kB is a fairly big `long` and a lot of garbage ones are going to be created. You could probably improve this by using [`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and processing more than one byte per iteration, but then you have to deal with the right endianness and everything. On Python 3 you also probably don't need the `ord()` since it should return the `bytes` type from IO methods.

Answer (score 1):

By referencing http://code.activestate.com/recipes/510399-byte-to-hex-and-hex-to-byte-string-conversion/ I found that the following code probably will run faster because it seems to be no arithmetic involved.

```
def ByteToHex( byteStr ):
    return ''.join( [ "%02X " % ord( x ) for x in byteStr ] ).strip()
```

Therefore, the task of, for example, reading 2-byte chunks as decimal numbers can be accomplished by the following code:

```
in_file=open("in-file", "rb")
piece = in_file.read(2)
a=ByteToHex(piece)
a=int(a,16)
```