# Converting Bit String To Bytes In Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, byte, bit, des

I am trying to implement DES algorithm in Python. After the encryption phase I got bit string as `"0010100100110100011001010011011101110111011110011000100010100011"`. Now I want to convert this bit string to bytes and write the data into the file. But the problem, is it contains non-readable characters. When I try to convert this into string, I got `)4e7wy£` and for doing so, I am using

```
def bits2String(b):
            return ''.join(chr(int(''.join(x), 2)) for x in zip(*[iter(b)]*8))
```

And further when I convert string to bytes, it adds extra characters which I don't want. So, how I can perform above task so that `)4e7wy£`can be as it is written in file in binary mode.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237926/convert-string-to-list-of-bits-and-viceversa) help?

Comment: Encode your file in `utf-8`? Your function returns the string just fine.

Comment: Actually, it contains some non utf-8 characters. When I typed that in question i.e. )4e7wy£ they got changed to utf-8 only @r.ook

Comment: I guess the answer is find out the proper encoding (`utf-16`?) and use that for your text output.  With your example however I am still able to save as a `utf-8` text file.