# Confused regarding encoding/decoding strings. How do I proceed before trying to implement base64?

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to do the first CryptoPals challenge where I have to implement the base64 algorithm. I am using Python.

It has the following advice:

> *Always operate on raw bytes, never on encoded strings. Only use hex and base64 for pretty-printing.*

So say I have a string and I have to convert this into bits. The issue is that I have seen people using UTF-8 or ASCII before converting the string to bytes/bits. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237926/convert-string-to-list-of-bits-and-viceversa))

Should I always proceed with UTF-8? Or there could be issues down the road if my script parses something encoded in ASCII?

Comment: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, thus all ASCII is valid UTF-8.

Comment: Oh man that was so quick. Thanks!