# How to convert binary string to ascii string in python?

Tags: python, binary, ascii

I've made a little python program that reads binary from a file and stores it to a text file, read the text file and store the binary. But, I can't get the binary to work...
it reads the files like this:

```
f_bin = open(bin_file,"rb")
to_bin_data = f_bin.read()
bin_data = bin(reduce(lambda x, y: 256*x+y, (ord(c) for c in to_bin_data), 0))
f_bin.close()
```

**this one doesen't work for me... [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa-python)**

Something like this webpage: http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp

**Edit: I've now made a long if else script for it, but thanks for the answers**

Comment: `f_bin.close` does not call anything, you have to append the `()`. Just as a hint, it does not belong to your problem.

Comment: I forgot to paste the brackets...

Comment: `doesen't work for me` is not very specific. What is your input `repr(to_bin_data)`? What is expected output, what do you get instead?

Answer (score 11):

Let's take the word 'hello' which is `0110100001100101011011000110110001101111`

To translate that back to characters we can use `chr` and `int` (with a base of 2) and some list slicing...

```
''.join(chr(int(bin_text[i:i+8], 2)) for i in xrange(0, len(bin_text), 8))
```

If we wanted to take 'hello' and convert it to binary we can use `ord` and string formatting...

```
''.join('{:08b}'.format(ord(c)) for c in 'hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use built-in functions:

```
>>> myString = "hello"
>>> ba = bytearray(myString)
>>> ba[0]
104
>>> bin(ba[0])
'0b1101000'
```

Split the `0b`:

```
>>> bin(ba[0]).split('b')[1]
'1101000'
```

or

```
>>> bin(ba[0])[2:]
'1101000'
```

I'll hope you can solve your problem with the snippets! :)

Comment: With `x = int('1101000', 2)` and `ba = bytearray([x])` and `str(ba)`.

Comment: `bin()` works but for consistency you need to zero-pad for a length of 8. (eg. `bin(3).split('b')[1]` is '11' and should be '00000011')

Comment: ''.join(map(binary_repr,bytearray("hello")))

Answer (score 2):

I use the struct module:

```
import struct
buf=struct.unpack('c',to_bin_data) # for one character
buf=struct.unpack('s',to_bin_data) # for a string
```

**edit:** sorry, misunderstood the question... This works for binary data, not for strings of binary representaion of characters.