# Python: Detect all strings in binary file?

Tags: python

[`strings`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings/) is a GNU/Linux app that prints the strings of printable characters in files.

Is there any way to do what `strings` does but in Python?

Calling `strings` and grabbing the output is not an option in my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python equivalent of unix "strings" utility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195924/python-equivalent-of-unix-strings-utility)

Answer (score 2):

if you don't care about the content of the output, it's very easy to achieve if you simple ignore all decoding error:

in python2:

```
with open('file') as fd:
    print fd.read().decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

in python3:

```
import codecs
with open('file') as fd:
    print(codecs.decode(fd.read(), 'ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

in any ways, `errors='ignore'` just ignore all errors during decoding.

further reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

python3: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html

Answer (score 2):

The following would print a list of all words of length 4 or more:

```
import re

with open(r"my_binary_file", "rb") as f_binary:
    print re.findall("([a-zA-Z]{4,})", f_binary.read())
```

By doing this, it cuts down on some non-text matches but might of course miss something you were looking for. `strings` also has a default value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Check byte by byte to see if it falls between 0x20 and 0x7F. That should print out if the byte is a readable ASCII character.

Answer (score 0):

The following should find all strings of length 4 and more (which is what `strings` does by default) in the bytes array:

```
def strings(data):
    cleansed = "".join(map(lambda byte: byte if byte >= chr(0x20) and byte <= chr(0x7F) else chr(0), data))
    return filter(lambda string: len(string) >= 4, cleansed.split(chr(0)))
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be "... and byte < chr(0x7F) else ...".
I believe that 0x7F(DEL) is not printable.