# How to print only printable charcters in binary file (equvalent to strings under Linux)?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am undertaking conversion of my python application from python 2 to python 3. One of the functions which I use is to get the printable character out of binary file. I earlier used following function in python 2 and it worked great:

```
import string

def strings(filename, min=4):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        result = ""
        for c in f.read():
            if c in string.printable:
                result += c
                continue
            if len(result) >= min:
                yield result
            result = ""
        if len(result) >= min:  # catch result at EOF
            yield result
```

Code is actually from [Python equivalent of unix "strings" utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195924/python-equivalent-of-unix-strings-utility). When I run the above code with python 2 it produces the output like this which is absolutely ok for me:

```
 +s
^!1^
i*Q(
}"~ 
%lh!ghY
#dh!
!`,!
mL#H
o!<XXT0
'   < 
z !Uk
%
 wS
n`  !wl
*ty

(Q  6
!XPLO$
E#kF
```

However, the function gives weird results under python 3. It produces the error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

So I converted the 'int' to 'str' by replacing this

```
if c in string.printable:
```

with this

```
if str(c) in string.printable:
```

(I also converted all the places where the same error message is thrown)

Now the python 3 gives the following output:

```
56700
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1236
60000
400234
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2340
0000
5010
5000
17889
2348
23400000000
5600
```

I cant see any characters when I use python 3. Any help to get the code working or pointer to the solution is appreciated. All I require is to extract the strings from binary file (very small with few kb) and store it in a variable.

Comment: You  have bytes in python3. Use `set(string.printable.encode())`

Comment: I don't know who down voted this question. But I request them to show the documentation and explanation the way 'Mr Martijn Pieters' did in his answer. If shown I will remove this post/question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, opening a file in binary mode gives you `bytes` results. Iterating over a `bytes` object gives you *integers*, not characters, in the range 0 to 255 (inclusive). From the [`bytes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, `bytes` objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that `0 <= x < 256`

Convert `string.printable` to a set and test against that:

```
printable = {ord(c) for c in string.printable}
```

and

```
if c in printable:
```

Next, you want to append to a `bytesarray()` object to keep things reasonably performant, and decode from ASCII to produce a `str` result:

```
printable = {ord(c) for c in string.printable}

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    result = bytearray()
    for c in f.read():
        if c in printable:
            result.append(c)
            continue
        if len(result) >= min:
            yield result.decode('ASCII')
            result.clear()
    if len(result) >= min:  # catch result at EOF
        yield result
```

Rather than iterate over the bytes one by one, you could instead split on anything that is *not* printable:

```
import re

nonprintable = re.compile(b'[^%s]+' % re.escape(string.printable.encode('ascii')))

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    for result in nonprintable.split(f.read()):
        if result:
            yield result.decode('ASCII')
```

I'd explore reading the file in *chunks* rather than in one go; don't try to fit a large file into memory in one go here:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    buffer = b''
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2048), b''):
        splitresult = nonprintable.split(buffer + chunk)            
        buffer = splitresult.pop()
        for string in splitresult:
            if string:
                yield string.decode('ascii')
    if buffer:
        yield buffer.decode('ascii')
```

The buffer carries over any incomplete word from one chunk to the next; `re.split()` produces empty values at the start and end if the input started or ended with non-printable characters, respectively.

Comment: And use `result = b""` as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: better use a `bytearray`; you can't append integers to a `byte` object..

Comment: true, it is one of those surprising things.  Iterate over `str` and get length 1 strs, but iterate over `bytes` and get integers.  `bytearray` makes more sense being mutable anyway.  `result += bytes([c])` would work, but not very efficient.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure this will work.

As a generator:

```py
import string, _io
def getPrintablesFromBinaryFile(path, encoding='cp1252'):
    global _io, string
    buffer = _io.BufferedReader(open(path, 'rb'))
    while True:
        byte = buffer.read(1)
        if byte == b'':
            return #EOF
        try:
            d = byte.decode(encoding)
        except:
            continue
        if d in string.printable:
            yield d
```

As a function is to just collect the outputs of the getPrintablesFromBinaryFile() into a iterable.

Explanation:

1. Import the needed modules
2. Define the function
3. Load the modules
4. Create the buffer
5. Get a byte from the buffer
6. Check if it is EOF
7. If yes, stop the generator
8. Try to decode using the encoding (like `'\xef'` does not decode using UTF-8)
9. If impossible, it cannot be a printable
10. If printable, yield it

**Note:** `cp1252` is the encoding for many text files

Comment: Why use `_io` and not `io`? And `open()` already returns a buffered reader, why wrap this again? Why decode by some arbitrary 8-bit codec? All characters in `string.printable` are ASCII characters; better to detect these before decoding and avoid that overhead. And since you read just 1 byte at a time you can't use any multi-byte codec *anyway*; it'd have been more logical to open the file in text mode. Also, don't use blanket `except` statements; catch specific exceptions instead. The OP code yields whole strings, you yield individual bytes, which isn't helpful.