# Multiplying a huge number times random() (Python)

Tags: python, optimization, largenumber

**Problem:** Generate large binary strings (length 2000+).  Do it quickly, as this generateRandom() function will be called 300,000 times in the algorithm.

**Attempted Solutions:** Generate 3 or 4 binary numbers and append them all together 500 times.  This is awfully slow.

Make a single call to random.random() and multiply it by a huge number.  Convert to binary once and be done.  This works for smaller numbers, but because the binary string must be a certain length, the number to convert to binary must be truly enormous (2 ** len(binString)).

**Current Code (works for smaller numbers):**

```
binaryRepresentation = ''

binaryRepresentation += bin(int(random.random() * (2 ** binLength)))[2:].zfill(binLength)
```

**Error that I need help fixing:** This call throws a "long int too large to convert to float" with the large numbers.  Is there a way to make the overall algorithm more efficient or to make this large number convert-able to a float?

*Thank you!*

Comment: What is the value of `binLength`?

Comment: @brianbuck: Anything over 1023 will be too big, and OP is looking for 2000+.

Comment: The approach of multiplying a float by some huge number isn't a good strategy.  The big number has way more digits than is representable by a float, so you're not randomizing all the digits.  If you want to convert a big integer into a "bit string" using the `bin` function, use `random.randint` instead of `random.random`.  Just `bin(random.randint(0, 2**binLength)[2:].zfill(binLength)`.

Comment: @JohnY: `randint()` will produce overflow if `getrandbits()` is not used [example](http://codepad.org/i9g3QqCQ).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It would appear older versions of Python don't necessarily use `getrandbits` in `randint`/`randrange`. So yes, to be sure, just use `getrandbits` (which I overlooked, because I never have this use case myself).

Comment: @JohnY: I feel rather dumb right now, having completely forgotten about just using a randint() call.  Everything is running much faster now, so thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeMausshardt: Don't feel so bad. Python comes with a lot of library functions, and most of us can't remember all of them. I forgot about `getrandbits` which is actually even more directly applicable to your requirements (and more reliable, as J.F. Sebastian points out).

Comment: I've added to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162190/4279) [`b2a_bin` C extension for Python](https://gist.github.com/3526111#file_b2a_bin.pyx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go from J.F. Sebastian's answer to a binary string (string with `0` and `1` characters in it):

```
>>> import random
>>> r = random.SystemRandom()
>>> bin(r.getrandbits(2000))[2:].zfill(2000)
'00010110001101100011000011001011011000010001010111000001111001001111010110010110011011110011101101100001111000011111010110100110011011110011111110010111111001110110011011011111011101000010101001001000100010001011011100011101100101010110001101101100100000001001010001101100110001100001101101010010001000010010010101100110100000001001001101000110001011111111111010011111111011001000100011001011011100010100010000010011100100011111011110111101010001001111011010101101010000110110010011000101111110000101001111100111111101101101110001100111011110011001000110110011101001010111100110000111000110011010000000111011001011100000100100111011110111101001110001110010010101100110000111001011100101111110100000100101011000110100111111001100111001000000111010000000101001111011111101111111101101011010010001101101101010011000100101000111000100100011010100111101111010001011110100100011111101101000111011100010000111000111110100001100111010001001010100001010111100001001010110010010100010011010010010011000000011010111110001100001100110101111011100010100100101000101000111110011111011011011111101011001001111010110000101100011111000111010100001000000101111011010011010011101011110000101011011110001111111101100000100000110111100011010110000111110110010100010010111111110010000000100001011110011100001001110110111100001101000011101011011101110001001001110011111111010001000100011010000110011000000000011111011011011101011010010001000101001011111110110000011000000000010101101111100011001010011100010010110111011001001011011010101111011101000001000011110010011111000011001110000100100111010000011100111110101110111010010101110010111100011111001101010010010000001010110011110001110010011011001110011000010010111111100101101100110111100001101100001100000101110000000011111010011000010000000011001101000001001000101001010100001110001011111110100110111000101011101111110010110001111111010100000100011011110011100010000000101001011100000010101101110110001110010111010000111101110100001100101000101010000110111011001001011'
>>> bin(r.getrandbits(2000))[2:].zfill(2000)
'11111011011010000011111101101101001110101011100110100011111011101101111100110001000110110100101010101000110010000101010100011111100111100010000001011011101100011101000001100101000101000010010000001111110101010011001110001001010011000011010100011111110111110010100000111011000000110000100000000110101101101111001101100000010010000100101001111100101010011101011010111110010001111111100101011110001101100111010010101110111000001000100101111011010001111001001010010000011100111101101101111101111010101100001000110011100110010110010101101001011000010101011111010010111000000100101100000100000010010000001000000001110010010100100111001011011111100111111001100000111111110011100001000111111110110001000010010110101100100001000001011110110100000111010101100111111010011111011111011000100101010111111000110111001001100011101101001000100110011001011101100010011010101111000011011111110001010110100100100001010100100100110101100111011110101001001111000010001101001010111111110011110111011111010001110011001000000100000101100001001100101000010011001101001110000101100000110000110101110011000010111110100100100100110010111110011101001000100111110011001101010000101100010011110100100110000111010111001000001101010101000001111001110010111000000101111101000110100101101000100000101100100110111101100010011110111011010111000111111100001110000100111001110001010101111000111100000011111111111110110100011000000111010100111011011100100010110100010110001111010110010100101111010111101110011010110100100010001001001110010110100111010010111001011101100000010011000110011011011010001100010000000010110011101101000111101000011101100001010001010001010111111110101100001110010000001010000000011000000000101111001001100100010110010000000101001010011110110111101111001110001001110111101011111111010101101011101010010111101000000010000101010100000101111010011010001001001101000001001011010110000000000111010001111001110100110000100011110100110110010011000111110100011000110001100001101101001010110001001001001101000011011101001010'
>>> bin(r.getrandbits(2000))[2:].zfill(2000)
'00100010111111011100001001000010100100101000100010101010100001011100101010100000000011111000001001011101010010010000101111111001101101100101011011001011110001001111101011101000101101000001000000110010011001110010101100101000011111001111111011011010001010010000011000000010011001101000100101000001001101001100010100000100100110000010110101011101011111010000010110011001101010010010000111001101101101001001100101111001101110111111111000011000001011011100111010011101001100011101011001110010111101011111010100101101010001011011001001010001111011100100101100100011111010010011110010011101100101001100111011011110011101010101010011001100000100110000001001111001111010011110110110001100110111011011111001110101000100100000011101001100111001100010001101010110000110010101010100011011101101010010100011111100001100100011010111000001011000101110100001111111001001111111101001000000011110110001010101001110110011000010101011010111111011010000011000000111110001110111111110110001110101011000010101001111110111101101010000111000011001111110101000001000011110000101011011001001000100010000110000110011100000100110100101011010011000110001010000101001110101111000110101001010010101000100011010101001110101101111010010101000011111101110110100101000110011010100010110110101010111001010110111011000000010001000110010011000011011110101101000111111101110100100011100000011110100000110111001001101110000011001101101011001000000101001110110011101111111010000000101111011100011010110111110000000001110101101100001001000001010000100101001111110110101000000101101111010010110000111101111011111100001111010001000100110111011010100110111011101011110001001001010100010101011001100100110101101111010011110001010011110000100100011101100101000000001011001010100101010011000011000100001011010010001010100001110101101100000010101011111010011000000000100100000000001011110101011101100101100010110101000111001010000001011000010001111101011111000011100101101110111110000011001000001101010001010000111001100101100111000111000001000000000'
```

With this benchmark:

```
import random
import time

def run(n):
    r = random.SystemRandom()
    for i in xrange(n):
        if i%30000 == 0: print i
        bin(r.getrandbits(2000))[2:].zfill(2000)

s = time.time()
run(300000)
e = time.time()
print "Took %.2fs" % (e-s,)
```

The result was `Took 12.32s`

Just getting the random bits without any string conversion (only `r.getrandbits(2000)`) took `7.77s`, so if you could find a way to use the random bits as a `long` then you'd save yourself some time.

Re-running the benchmark using `os.urandom(250)` instead (without additional processing) took only `3.59s`, so that seems to be the fastest option.

Comment: you could use [`"{:0{}b}".format(r.getrandbits(k), k)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162190/4279) to produce the binary string (a string with "0"s and "1"s).

Comment: i actually tried that and it ended up a second or two slower (`13.5s`). actually in python 2.6 that formatting string didn't work so i ended up having to do `"{0:02000b}".format(r.getrandbits(2000))`

Comment: In [my measurements](https://gist.github.com/3526111#file_test_b2a_bin.py) `bin` also slightly faster than `"".format` for small input.

Answer (score 5):

Measure whether it is fast enough for your purposes, "randomness" might diminish the more you call it: [`os.urandom(250)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom). It produces a binary string aka bytes.

To avoid  "long int too large to convert to float" error don't use floats.

If you need an integer with `k` random bits instead of a binary string:

```
import random
r = random.SystemRandom()

n = r.getrandbits(2000) # uses os.urandom() under the hood
```

To get a string of "0"s and "1"s:

```
k = 2000
binstr = "{:0{}b}".format(r.getrandbits(k), k)
```

Note: you can't use `randint/randrange` for large numbers if `getrandbits` is not used:

```
import random

class R(random.Random):
    def random(self): # override random to suppress getrandbits usage
        return random.random()

r = R()
r.randrange(2**2000) # -> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

### b2a_bin

[`b2a_bin()` extension](https://gist.github.com/3526111) allows to create binary strings ("01") directly from bytestrings without creating an intermediate Python integer. It is 3-20 times faster than pure Python analogs:

```
def b2a_bin_bin(data):
    return bin(int.from_bytes(data, 'big', signed=False)
               )[2:].zfill(len(data)*8).encode('ascii', 'strict')

def b2a_bin_format(data):
    n = int.from_bytes(data, 'big', signed=False)
    return "{:0{}b}".format(n, len(data)*8).encode('ascii', 'strict')
```

Usage:

```
>>> import os
>>> from b2a_bin import b2a_bin
>>> b2a_bin.b2a_bin(b'\x0a')
b'00001010'
>>> b2a_bin(os.urandom(5))
b'1001111011000011111001110010000101111010'
```

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, OP wants 2000+ *bits*, while `urandom` returns a number of *bytes*, so he just needs to divide his required bits by 8.  But this is definitely the simplest, most random, and probably fastest approach.

Comment: `urandom` will stall (atleast on linux) when `/dev/urandom` runs out of data to be read.

Comment: @JohnY: the question contradicts itself. The first sentence "Generate large binary strings (length 2000+)."

Comment: @Pykler: "u" stands for "unlocked"/non-blocking. `os.urandom()` should gradually use more bits from PRNG if there is not enough entropy hence "randomness might diminish" remark above.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I'm not entirely sure what contradiction you are referring to. There is often confusion surrounding the term "binary string", because some people are referring to actual bits while others are referring to a string of characters, where the characters may be '0' or '1'. And there may be other cases I'm not thinking of. But clearly, the OP gave enough context to demonstrate that he wants a character string (the output of `bin` minus leading '0b' and padded as necessary).

Comment: @JohnY: you're right. I (incorrectly in this case) assumed that binary string means bytes object. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Pykler: I've ran: `timeit.Timer("_r(2000)", "import os; _r=os.urandom").repeat(3, 1000*1000)` on a linux box. The result: `[153.47017002105713, 155.28154397010803, 155.71952104568481]`

Comment: Hmm... when I said this was "probably fastest" I didn't take into account conversion into the form that OP seems to want.  I don't know what is the fastest way to convert from 2000 *actual bits* to a string of 2000 zero and one characters.  If it takes two steps, then the `randint`/`randrange` approach, with `bin`, may be faster.

Comment: @JohnY: you'll get either overflow due to `int(random() * n)` (same is in the question) or `randint()` will use `getrandbits()` under the hood.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I have already tried `randint` and it works. If it uses `getrandbits`, that's fine. The point is, `bin` with a (big) integer argument is a convenient and pretty efficient way to get the output in the form OP wants. If there is a faster/simpler way, I don't know it.

Comment: @JohnY: I prefer `"{:0{}b}".format(r.getrandbits(k), k)` It avoids ugly `bin()[2:].zfill()` that breaks for negative numbers in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Is `random.randrange` really too slow? Let's see how slow it really is.

```
import random

word_size = 2048
word_max = 2 ** word_size

def random_bits(n):
    """
    Return a string consisting of `n` zeroes and ones (chosen randomly).
    """
    def words():
        s, m, r = word_size, word_max, n % word_size
        for _ in range(n // s):
            yield bin(random.randrange(m))[2:].zfill(s)
        yield bin(random.randrange(2 ** r))[2:].zfill(r)
    return ''.join(words())

>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer(lambda:random_bits(2000)).timeit(number=300000)
9.680696964263916
```

10 seconds doesn't seem an absurd amount of time for choosing 600 million random bits. So perhaps you can say more about your speed requirement. Is this really too slow?