# How to return a number as a binary string with a set number of bits in python

Tags: python, binary

Probably a silly question, but in python is there a simple way to automatically pad a number with zeros to a fixed length? I wasn't able to find this in the python docs, but I may not have been looking hard enough? e.i. I want bin(4) to return 00100, rather than just 100. Is there a simple way to ensure the output will be six bits instead of three?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings have a `.zfill()` method to pad it with zeros:

```
>>> '100'.zfill(5)
'00100'
```

For binary numbers however, I'd use string formatting:

```
>>> '{0:05b}'.format(4)
'00100'
```

The `:05b` formatting specification formats the number passed in as binary, with 5 digits, zero padded. See the [Python format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). I've used [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) here, but the [built-in `format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) can take the same formatting instruction, minus the `{0:..}` placeholder syntax:

```
>>> format(4, '05b')
'00100'
```

if you find that easier.

Comment: Ah, fantastic! Just what I was looking for. Bonus points for including both solutions, which is why once this one is accepted over others.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: `bin/zfill` is slightly faster than `format` in [my measurements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161988/multiplying-a-huge-number-times-random-python#comment16331044_12162856).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I see no measurements for `format()`, only `str.format()`. `str.format()` requires a parsing step, then filling the slots, which internally then uses `format()`. To compare with `bin/zfill`, you need to not incur that extra cost.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes. My older comment uses `"".format` that hints at that. Though I don't know what is "fair" translation of: `"{:0{}b}".format(n, len(data)*8)` (it is compared against `bin(n)[2:].zfill(len(data)*8)`) using only `format()` e.g., `format(n, "0%db" % (len(data)*8))` has performed **worse**.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The length cannot be pre-computed? Why not compare `bin()/zfill()` and `format()` with a fixed length?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `data` is the input for [the functions that are compared](https://gist.github.com/zed/3526111#file-test_b2a_bin-py-L16) -- it can't be eliminated. The only benchmark that matters is your application  on the hardware it is deployed; that Is why I said *"my measurements"*

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: but if you are going to use those measurements to make general statements about performance then you need to either state those constraints or re-do them for the more general context. :-)

Comment: 1. I've stated it twice already. Here's the 3rd time to be sure: *"in my measurements"*  2. I'm not sure my use case is less relevant for @SlaterTyranus than a static format case. And I'm not sure it is valid to call a static length to be more general than a variable length. 3. And `format()` is still slightly slower than `bin/zfill` even with static length *on examples that I've tried by hand*. :)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yeah, I hadn't missed the *in my measurements* part. :-)

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
In [11]: x = 1

In [12]: print str(x).zfill(5)
00001

In [13]: bin(4)
Out[13]: '0b100'

In [14]: str(bin(4)[2:]).zfill(5)
Out[14]: '00100'
```

Comment: +1 for using [2:] to strip the '0b' off the binary literal. that caught me at first.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for the [*format*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#format) built-in function:

```
>>> format(4, '05b')
'00100'
```