# Binary representation of float in Python (bits not hex)

Tags: python, binary, floating-point

How can I get a string of `0`s and `1`s, according to the bits of the IEEE 754 representation of a 32 bit float?

For example, given an input `1.00`, the result should be `'00111111100000000000000000000000'`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can do that with the `struct` package:

```
import struct
def binary(num):
    return ''.join('{:0>8b}'.format(c) for c in struct.pack('!f', num))
```

That packs it as a network byte-ordered float, and then converts each of the resulting bytes into an 8-bit binary representation and concatenates them out:

```
>>> binary(1)
'00111111100000000000000000000000'
```

**Edit**:
There was a request to expand the explanation. I'll expand this using intermediate variables to comment each step.

```
def binary(num):
    # Struct can provide us with the float packed into bytes. The '!' ensures that
    # it's in network byte order (big-endian) and the 'f' says that it should be
    # packed as a float. Alternatively, for double-precision, you could use 'd'.
    packed = struct.pack('!f', num)
    print 'Packed: %s' % repr(packed)

    # For each character in the returned string, we'll turn it into its corresponding
    # integer code point
    # 
    # [62, 163, 215, 10] = [ord(c) for c in '>\xa3\xd7\n']
    integers = [ord(c) for c in packed]
    print 'Integers: %s' % integers

    # For each integer, we'll convert it to its binary representation.
    binaries = [bin(i) for i in integers]
    print 'Binaries: %s' % binaries

    # Now strip off the '0b' from each of these
    stripped_binaries = [s.replace('0b', '') for s in binaries]
    print 'Stripped: %s' % stripped_binaries

    # Pad each byte's binary representation's with 0's to make sure it has all 8 bits:
    #
    # ['00111110', '10100011', '11010111', '00001010']
    padded = [s.rjust(8, '0') for s in stripped_binaries]
    print 'Padded: %s' % padded

    # At this point, we have each of the bytes for the network byte ordered float
    # in an array as binary strings. Now we just concatenate them to get the total
    # representation of the float:
    return ''.join(padded)
```

And the result for a few examples:

```
>>> binary(1)
Packed: '?\x80\x00\x00'
Integers: [63, 128, 0, 0]
Binaries: ['0b111111', '0b10000000', '0b0', '0b0']
Stripped: ['111111', '10000000', '0', '0']
Padded: ['00111111', '10000000', '00000000', '00000000']
'00111111100000000000000000000000'

>>> binary(0.32)
Packed: '>\xa3\xd7\n'
Integers: [62, 163, 215, 10]
Binaries: ['0b111110', '0b10100011', '0b11010111', '0b1010']
Stripped: ['111110', '10100011', '11010111', '1010']
Padded: ['00111110', '10100011', '11010111', '00001010']
'00111110101000111101011100001010'
```

Comment: The benefit of this method is that it's trivially easy to convert to 64-bit floats if needed.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- you might be right, but it seems like there is an awful lot of string manipulation which is going on for each bit that doesn't need to be done ...

Comment: I agree with @mgilson -- I actually prefer his solution, but with a single final `replace` and `rjust` to 32 (or 64), rather than one for each byte.

Comment: I've added my own answer, not sure it's any cleaner. There really should be a version of `bin` that does the right thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `bin(struct.unpack('!Q', struct.pack('!d', -1.))[0])[2:].zfill(64)` works for doubles (64-bit floats).

Comment: For Python 3 you must omit the call to ord() since pack() returns a bytes object which yields integers directly when iterated over.

Comment: This works great. But can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: If I do `b = np.nextafter(a, -2)`, `binary(a) == binary(b)` is True, even though `a != b`.  (Oh, because it's double, not float.)

Comment: A shorter Python 3 version: `''.join('{:0>8b}'.format(c) for c in struct.pack('!f', num))`

Comment: @CristianCiupitu 's solution was the only one that worked for me. I am using python 3.

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found. What am I missing?

Comment: @Cristian-Ciupitu, what do you do to check the binary representation of double-precision numbers? I suppose they are stored in another 4 bytes, so how do I modify your version please?

Comment: @gciriani replace the float format (`f`) with the [double format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) (`d`), i.e. `''.join('{:0>8b}'.format(c) for c in struct.pack('!f', num))`

Comment: What is the computational cost of `code ''.join(bin(c).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') for c in struct.pack('!f', num))`?

Answer (score 42):

Here's an ugly one ...

```
>>> import struct
>>> bin(struct.unpack('!i',struct.pack('!f',1.0))[0])
'0b111111100000000000000000000000'
```

Basically, I just used the struct module to convert the float to an int ...

---

Here's a slightly better one using `ctypes`:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> bin(ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer(ctypes.c_float(1.0)).value)
'0b111111100000000000000000000000'
```

Basically, I construct a `float` and use the same memory location, but I tag it as a `c_uint32`.  The `c_uint32`'s value is a python integer which you can use the builtin `bin` function on.

**Note**: by switching types we can do reverse operation as well

```py
>>> ctypes.c_float.from_buffer(ctypes.c_uint32(int('0b111111100000000000000000000000', 2))).value
1.0
```

also for double-precision 64-bit float we can use the same trick using `ctypes.c_double` & `ctypes.c_uint64` instead.

Comment: it relies on `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` (use `'!'` to force `4` bytes for `i` format). `ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)` might depend on platform. There is `int.from_bytes()` on Python 3.2+

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- I suppose I'm also assuming that `bin` returns the IEEE standard representation...

Comment: I suppose I don't either.  The `bin` function doesn't guarantee much about the output -- Only that it is an object that python can handle.  If the `sizeof(int) != sizeof(float)` then it's not using IEEE 754 (is it?).  In that case, the bit pattern returned by `bin` could be anything as well -- e.g. the bits could be reported backward or something due to different endianness.  The sign bit could be some place else, etc. etc.

Comment: `sizeof(int) != sizeof(float)` issue is unrelated to `bin()` (that works on Python integers that are unlimited). To support negative floats, [use `!I` format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex/16444786?noredirect=1#comment23588679_16444990).

Comment: I'm sorry for the massive necro on this one, but I have to make a correction for the `ctypes` variant: when working with negative numbers the result is all wrong, probably due to python applying 2's complement or some other shenanigans somewhere in the middle. When trying your example with the number -1.0 the actual encoded IEEE 754 in the result was 4.0 (`'-0b1000000100000000000000000000000'`)... It seems to work correctly when replacing `ctypes.c_int` in your example with `ctypes.c_uint`. EDIT: massive kudos for the quick response! :)

Answer (score 35):

Found another solution using the [bitstring](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/) module.

```
import bitstring
f1 = bitstring.BitArray(float=1.0, length=32)
print(f1.bin)
```

Output:

```
00111111100000000000000000000000
```

Comment: One can verify the value from the following website: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 20):

For the sake of completeness, you can achieve this with numpy using:

```
f = 1.00
int32bits = np.asarray(f, dtype=np.float32).view(np.int32).item()  # item() optional
```

You can then print this, with padding, using the `b` format specifier

```
print('{:032b}'.format(int32bits))
```

Comment: slightly neater: `int32bits = np.float32(1.0).view(np.int32)`

Comment: Still need the `.item()` if you truly want a python `int`

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Otherwise, you have an `np.int32` object

Comment: still neat: `int32bits = np.float32(1.0).view(np.int32).item()` :)

Comment: int32bits = np.float32(-3.03).view(np.uint32).item() to put the sign just once

Comment: how to convert the same binary value generated back to float?

Comment: This is the best answer as it generalizes to `np.float16` types, which have no native equivalent in Python.

Answer (score 12):

With these two simple functions (**Python >=3.6**) you can easily convert a float number to binary and vice versa, for IEEE 754 binary64.

```py
import struct

def bin2float(b):
    ''' Convert binary string to a float.

    Attributes:
        :b: Binary string to transform.
    '''
    h = int(b, 2).to_bytes(8, byteorder="big")
    return struct.unpack('>d', h)[0]


def float2bin(f):
    ''' Convert float to 64-bit binary string.

    Attributes:
        :f: Float number to transform.
    '''
    [d] = struct.unpack(">Q", struct.pack(">d", f))
    return f'{d:064b}'
```

For example:

```py
print(float2bin(1.618033988749894))
print(float2bin(3.14159265359))
print(float2bin(5.125))
print(float2bin(13.80))

print(bin2float('0011111111111001111000110111011110011011100101111111010010100100'))
print(bin2float('0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010111011101010'))
print(bin2float('0100000000010100100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'))
print(bin2float('0100000000101011100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010'))
```

The output is:

```sh
0011111111111001111000110111011110011011100101111111010010100100
0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010111011101010
0100000000010100100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0100000000101011100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
1.618033988749894
3.14159265359
5.125
13.8
```

I hope you like it, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: also -- why are you using `struct.unpack('>Q', ...)` instead of `int.from_bytes(..., 'big')`?

Comment: You're right, that `decode` line has infiltrated unintentionally, I've edited it. Thanks for notifying.

Regarding your last comment, use `struct` because the parameter that receives the function is a float, not an int, and the float don't have the `to_bytes()` method available.

If you can think of a better way to do it, it's welcome :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you have time, could you please look at this example? If I understand things correctly, the floating point representation of `1.0` is `.100...0 * 2^(00000000001)` where the exponent has 11 bits and the mantissa has 52. Thus, I think the floating representation of `1.0` should be `00000000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. I tried `float2bin(1.0)` and the result was `0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Could you please explain the difference?

Answer (score 10):

This problem is more cleanly handled by breaking it into two parts.

The first is to convert the float into an int with the equivalent bit pattern:

```
import struct
def float32_bit_pattern(value):
    return sum(ord(b) << 8*i for i,b in enumerate(struct.pack('f', value)))
```

Python 3 doesn't require `ord` to convert the bytes to integers, so you need to simplify the above a little bit:

```
def float32_bit_pattern(value):
    return sum(b << 8*i for i,b in enumerate(struct.pack('f', value)))
```

Next convert the int to a string:

```
def int_to_binary(value, bits):
    return bin(value).replace('0b', '').rjust(bits, '0')
```

Now combine them:

```
>>> int_to_binary(float32_bit_pattern(1.0), 32)
'00111111100000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: `float32_bit_pattern` can be defined as `lambda x: int.from_bytes(struct.pack("f", x), byteorder="little")` on Python 3.2+

Comment: does not compile.

Comment: @noobcoder sorry, Python 3 doesn't require `ord` to convert the output of `struct.pack`.  And I forgot to mention `import struct`.

Answer (score 5):

Piggy-tailing on Dan's answer with colored version for Python3:

```
import struct

BLUE = "\033[1;34m"
CYAN = "\033[1;36m"
GREEN = "\033[0;32m"
RESET = "\033[0;0m"


def binary(num):
    return [bin(c).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') for c in struct.pack('!f', num)]


def binary_str(num):
    bits = ''.join(binary(num))
    return ''.join([BLUE, bits[:1], GREEN, bits[1:10], CYAN, bits[10:], RESET])


def binary_str_fp16(num):
    bits = ''.join(binary(num))
    return ''.join([BLUE, bits[:1], GREEN, bits[1:10][-5:], CYAN, bits[10:][:11], RESET])

x = 0.7
print(x, "as fp32:", binary_str(0.7), "as fp16 is sort of:", binary_str_fp16(0.7))
```

[image: colored representation]

Answer (score 2):

After browsing through lots of similar questions I've written something which hopefully does what I wanted.

```
f = 1.00
negative = False
if f < 0:
    f = f*-1
    negative = True

s = struct.pack('>f', f)
p = struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]
hex_data =  hex(p)

scale = 16
num_of_bits = 32
binrep = bin(int(hex_data, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)
if negative:
    binrep = '1' + binrep[1:]
```

`binrep` is the result.
Each part will be explained.

---

```
f = 1.00
negative = False
if f < 0:
    f = f*-1
    negative = True
```

Converts the number to a positive if negative, and sets the variable negative to false. The reason for this is that the difference between positive and negative binary representations is just in the first bit, and this was the simpler way than to figure out what goes wrong when doing the whole process with negative numbers.

---

```
s = struct.pack('>f', f)                          #'?\x80\x00\x00'
p = struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]                     #1065353216
hex_data =  hex(p)                                #'0x3f800000'
```

`s` is a hex representation of the binary `f`. it is however not in the pretty form i need. Thats where p comes in. It is the int representation of the hex s. And then another conversion to get a pretty hex.

---

```
scale = 16
num_of_bits = 32
binrep = bin(int(hex_data, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)
if negative:
    binrep = '1' + binrep[1:]
```

`scale` is the base 16 for the hex. `num_of_bits` is 32, as float is 32 bits, it is used later to fill the additional places with 0 to get to 32. Got the code for `binrep` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859937/1214214). If the number was negative, just change the first bit.

---

I know this is ugly, but i didn't find a nice way and I needed it fast. Comments are welcome.

Comment: `bin(struct.unpack('!I', struct.pack('!f', -1.))[0])[2:].zfill(32)` supports positive/negative floats. To improve performance you could modify [`b2a_bin(struct.pack('!f', -1.))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162190/4279) to accept floats directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more than was asked, but it was what I needed when I found this entry.  This code will give the mantissa, base and sign of the IEEE 754 32 bit float.

```
import ctypes
def binRep(num):
    binNum = bin(ctypes.c_uint.from_buffer(ctypes.c_float(num)).value)[2:]
    print("bits: " + binNum.rjust(32,"0"))
    mantissa = "1" + binNum[-23:]
    print("sig (bin): " + mantissa.rjust(24))
    mantInt = int(mantissa,2)/2**23
    print("sig (float): " + str(mantInt))
    base = int(binNum[-31:-23],2)-127
    print("base:" + str(base))
    sign = 1-2*("1"==binNum[-32:-31].rjust(1,"0"))
    print("sign:" + str(sign))
    print("recreate:" + str(sign*mantInt*(2**base)))

binRep(-0.75)
```

output:

```
bits: 10111111010000000000000000000000
sig (bin): 110000000000000000000000
sig (float): 1.5
base:-1
sign:-1
recreate:-0.75
```

Comment: When verifying this script with sqrt(2), it seems to give only 6 decimal digits correct. Is there a bug somewhere? 2**.5 = 1.4142135623730951 but your script outputs for binRep(2**.5) the following, recreate:1.4142135381698608.

Answer (score 1):

Convert float between 0..1

```
def float_bin(n, places = 3): 
    if (n < 0 or n > 1):
        return "ERROR, n must be in 0..1"
    
    answer = "0."
    while n > 0:
        if len(answer) - 2 == places: 
            return answer
        
        b = n * 2
        if b >= 1:
            answer += '1'
            n = b - 1
        else:
            answer += '0'
            n = b
            
    return answer
```

Comment: I fixed the code: the length check did not take the leading zero and the dot into account and `b > 1` must be `b >= 1`.  Test results: 0 is "0.", 0.5 is "0.1", 0.25 is "0.01", 0.125 is "0.001", and 0.1 is "0.0001100110" (with places = 10).

Answer (score 0):

Several of these answers did not work as written with Python 3, or did not give the correct representation for negative floating point numbers. I found the following to work for me (though this gives 64-bit representation which is what I needed)

```
def float_to_binary_string(f):
    def int_to_8bit_binary_string(n):
        stg=bin(n).replace('0b','')
        fillstg = '0'*(8-len(stg))
        return fillstg+stg
    return ''.join( int_to_8bit_binary_string(int(b)) for b in struct.pack('>d',f) )
```

Comment: Perhaps it is important to mention that `>d` is for big endian doubles (8 byte numbers) and `<d` is for little endian doubles.

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple one. please check it. and if you think there was any mistake please let me know. this works fine for me.

```
sds=float(input("Enter the number : "))
sf=float("0."+(str(sds).split(".")[-1]))
aa=[]

while len(aa)<15:
    dd=round(sf*2,5)
    if dd-1>0:
        
        aa.append(1)
        sf=dd-1
        
    else:
        
        sf=round(dd,5)
        aa.append(0)
    
des=aa[:-1]
print("\n")
AA=([str(i) for i in des])

print("So the Binary Of : %s>>>"%sds,bin(int(str(sds).split(".")[0])).replace("0b",'')+"."+"".join(AA))
```

or in case of integer number just use `bin(integer).replace("0b",'')`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .format for the easiest representation of bits in my opinion:

my code would look something like:

```
def fto32b(flt):
# is given a 32 bit float value and converts it to a binary string
if isinstance(flt,float):
    # THE FOLLOWING IS AN EXPANDED REPRESENTATION OF THE ONE LINE RETURN
            #   packed = struct.pack('!f',flt) <- get the hex representation in (!)Big Endian format of a (f) Float
            #   integers = []
            #   for c in packed:
            #       integers.append(ord(c))    <- change each entry into an int
            #   binaries = []
            #   for i in integers:
            #       binaries.append("{0:08b}".format(i)) <- get the 8bit binary representation of each int (00100101)
            #   binarystring = ''.join(binaries) <- join all the bytes together
            #   return binarystring
    return ''.join(["{0:08b}".format(i) for i in [ord(c) for c in struct.pack('!f',flt)]])
return None
```

Output:

```
>>> a = 5.0
'01000000101000000000000000000000'
>>> b = 1.0
'00111111100000000000000000000000'
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's use numpy!

```
import numpy as np

def binary(num, string=True):
    bits = np.unpackbits(np.array([num]).view('u1'))
    if string:
        return np.array2string(bits, separator='')[1:-1]
    else:
        return bits
```

e.g.,

```
binary(np.pi)
# '0001100000101101010001000101010011111011001000010000100101000000'

binary(np.pi, string=False)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
#       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
#       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#      dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: This gives incorrect results for every input I tried.