# how can I convert a binary float to a base 10 float and vice versa?

Tags: python, binary, floating-point, decimal, python-2.x

I have a binary float like '10.1' and want to convert it to a decimal float. Then I want to do some operations on it and convert it back to a binary float. Are there builtins in python 2 to do this? If not, what is the shortest (in bytes) way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example? What does the binary float "10.1" look like as a decimal float? What operations will you do on it? And what will it look like when you convert it back?

Comment: @Kevin it would look like "2.1". The operations done is just an eval(). There is a string with binary floats, each are converted to base 10 float, then the string is evaluated, and the result is converted back to binary float.

Comment: Is 2.1 the actual number it would be converted to, or is that just an example of what it would "look" like?

Comment: Check [this out](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point_number_to_binary#Python)

Comment: Really "2.1"? Or did you mean "2.5"?

Comment: @MarkDickinson sorry, you are correct...That is what I meant

Comment: @BobDylan so there isn't a builtin way of doing this?

Comment: [You can do this with the `struct` package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16444778/5221082), but you're just doing glorified string manipulation. The underlying data structure is still not what you're after.

Comment: Are you actually interested in the shortest in bytes solution? Because that'd be code golf and it might result in something unintuitive and unreadable. I think you meant something along the lines *not verbose, but short, readable and efficient*.

Comment: @Reti43 yes, and having done code golf for several months I get the gist of it. It would be fine if the answerer includes an ungolfed version for other readers perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do this for binary (though there is from [hexadecimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex)). The easiest way would be to strip out the `.`, parse as an integer, and scale appropriately:

```
import math
x = "10.1"
p = len(x) - x.index(".") - 1
i = int(x.replace(".",""),2)
math.ldexp(i,-p)
```

This assumes your string consists of nothing but `0`s, `1`s and a single `.` (i.e. no whitespace or exponent).

Comment: `p=x[::-1].index('.')`