# python , bit represantation

Tags: python-3.x, bit

I'm creating a 8-bits number with numpy:

```
a = numpy.uint8(2)
```

and сall :

```
bin(a)
```

> Result : ob10 ,but I want to have a representation where all bits of
>   my numbers filled : 00000010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary representation of float in Python (bits not hex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex)

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
def getBits(a):
    binary=bin(a)
    zeros_required=8-(len(binary)-2)
    return '0'*zeros_required+binary[2:]
```

Comment: I would recommend using `.zfill()` for that, i.e. `return bin(a)[2:].zfill(8)`.