# How can I interpret a float32 as four uint8s in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-operators

I tried to use python to read points cloud data files, which with extension ".pcd". They store RGBA color information with just one numpy float32.
How can i convert the `float32` data type into 4 `uint8` numbers in python ?
For example, what is the rgb value hidden in number 4.51073351e-39 ?

```
In [13]: pc.pc_data["rgb"]
Out[13]: 
array([  4.51073351e-39,   4.41853788e-39,   4.87845245e-39, ...,
         3.31220574e-39,   2.94594696e-39,   3.12997949e-39], dtype=float32)
```

Here is the link to download the dataset: http://rgbd-dataset.cs.washington.edu/dataset/rgbd-dataset_pcd_ascii/apple_1.tar

And i used pypcd to read the file: here is the pypcd github link:https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd

Comment: those values seem very very low... are you sure the format is OK?

Comment: possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex

Comment: @corn3lius: None of the answers there are good practice when using numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `pc.pc_data["rgb"].view((np.uint8, 4))`, which for your example gives:

```
array([[23, 30, 49,  0],
       [22, 29, 48,  0],
       [36, 31, 53,  0],
       ...
       [21, 17, 36,  0],
       [26, 20, 32,  0],
       [28, 21, 34,  0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Really late to the party, but pypcd (author here) actually has this function as `decode_rgb_from_pcl`, you can call it as `pypcd.decode_rgb_from_pcl(pc.pc_data['rgb'])`. Admittedly, I like the way @Eric implemented this better than mine :D