# Tensorflow bit-wise NOT operation for floats

Tags: tensorflow, bit-manipulation

I have a Tensorflow boolean vector that I need to bit-wise invert such that all the values that are 0 (False) becomes 1 (True) and vice-versa. [tf.logical_not](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/logical_operators) exists, but it only takes Boolean vectors. Does there exist a Tensorflow that does this on a vector of ints or floats so I don't need to recast my tensor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TensorFlow doesn't include a specific operator for performing bitwise NOT, but you could simulate it with [`tf.bitcast()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/casting#bitcast) and arithmetic operations on integers. For example, the following will invert the bits in a single floating-point value:

```
input_value = tf.constant(37.0)

bitcast_to_int32 = tf.bitcast(input_value, tf.int32)

invert_bits = tf.constant(-1) - bitcast_to_int32

bitcast_to_float = tf.bitcast(invert_bits, tf.float32)
```

You can confirm that the input and output are bitwise inverses using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16444778/3574081) to convert the floating-point values to binary.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to [`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/casting#cast) the tensor to `tf.bool` then invoke [`tf.logical_not`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/logical_operators#logical_not) then cast back.

```
dtype = tensor.dtype
btensor = tf.cast(tensor, tf.bool)
not_tensor = tf.logical_not(btensor)
tensor = tf.cast(not_tensor, dtype)
```

Comment: If it is per-value, as opposed to bitwise, then how about x = 1. - x