# Float representation of binary in Python (bits not hex)

Tags: python, binary, floating-point

How to get the 32 bit float representation of a string as binary IEEE 754?

Example

'00111111100000000000000000000000' -> 1.00

This question is the reverse of:
[Binary representation of float in Python (bits not hex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex)
and I couldn't find the answer elsewhere. Please note that I am very new to coding so please be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> n = '00111111100000000000000000000000'
>>> struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('i', int(n, 2)))[0]
1.0
```

- `int(.., 2)` to convert the binary representation to `int` (base 2)
- `struct.pack('i', ..)` to convert bytes (`i`: 32bit int)
- `struct.unpack('f', ...)[0]` to convert bytes back to float.

For other `struct` format character, see [Format charactes - `struct` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).