# How to converting floating point number

Tags: python, python-3.x

A converting between the decimal to single-precision floating,but i intro to this,so did any useful references or any summarize can help?

Thousand Thanks!

so,the python function will be like

1. require a user to select convert from decimal to to floating point number or floating point number convert to decimal.
2. input value
3. will show the step such as

   i. Sign

   ii. Exponent

   iii. Mantissa
4. return the result.

---

- [This Link is The example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-representation-digital-logic/)
- [This link C programming example about this question](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-conversion-of-32-bits-single-precision-ieee-754-floating-point-representation/)
- [This link is 64bit python conversion](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/converting-between-binary-and-decimal-representations-of-ieee-754-floating-point-numbers-in-c/)

**below is the example i searched from internet but this is 64bit so,how change it to 32bit and show the step when converting?**

```
    import struct

getBin = lambda x: x > 0 and str(bin(x))[2:] or "-" + str(bin(x))[3:]

def floatToBinary64(value):
    val = struct.unpack('Q', struct.pack('d', value))[0]
    return getBin(val)

def binaryToFloat(value):
    hx = hex(int(value, 2))   
    return struct.unpack("d", struct.pack("q", int(hx, 16)))[0]

# floats are represented by IEEE 754 floating-point format which are 
# 64 bits long (not 32 bits)

# float to binary
binstr = floatToBinary64(19.5)
print('Binary equivalent of 19.5:')
print(binstr + '\n')

# binary to float
fl = binaryToFloat(binstr)
print('Decimal equivalent of ' + binstr)
print(fl)
```

Comment: Could you clarify the formats (and Python types) of the inputs and outputs? Some examples might help, too.

Comment: It makes not much sense to convert a float to a decimal. Since due to rounding errors, the values will not be very accurate.

Comment: what about numpy.float32( ... )?

Comment: @MarkDickinson i had updated the question,thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i had create a example link that with C language,but i am looking for python,thanks.

Comment: @Stef sry, i can't understand what your mean,can explain in details? thanks.

Comment: You have example code for 64 bit conversion, and you should be able to find the IEE754 specification so unless you want someone to write the code for you (which is off-topic for stackoverflow, because Stackoverflow is not a code writing service) you have all the information needed to write the code yourself.

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-repreentation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex: `''.join('{:0>8b}'.format(c) for c in struct.pack('!f', num))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-repreentation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex) SO question we get:

```
import struct

def floatToBinary32(value):
    return ''.join(f'{c:0>8b}' for c in struct.pack('!f', value))

def binaryToFloat(value):
    hx = hex(int(value, 2))   
    return struct.unpack("f", struct.pack("l", int(hx, 16)))[0]

# float to binary
fl0 = 19.5
binstr = floatToBinary32(fl0)
print(f'Binary equivalent of {fl0}: {binstr}')

# binary to float
fl1 = binaryToFloat(binstr)
print(f'Decimal equivalent of      {binstr}: {fl1}')

print(f'\nSign     ( 1 bit ) = {binstr[0]}\nExponent ( 8 bits) = {binstr[1:9]}\nMantissa (23 bits) = {binstr[9:]}')

assert fl0 == fl1
```

Output:

```
Binary equivalent of 19.5: 01000001100111000000000000000000
Decimal equivalent of      01000001100111000000000000000000: 19.5

Sign     ( 1 bit ) = 0
Exponent ( 8 bits) = 10000011
Mantissa (23 bits) = 00111000000000000000000
```

Please note however that, as already pointed out in the comments above, such conversions are not exact as you can see when using for example `fl0 = 0.1`. This also shows that python (CPython) uses 64 bit floats (implemented using double in C).

Comment: hi,thanks for helping me about this question. i check on this have some problem with return struct.unpack("f", struct.pack("l", int(hx, 16)))[0],but i had modified, and it worked now. A thousand thanks again! :)