# pythonic way to get the binary32 representation of a number (int, float, or double)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, ieee-754

Related to [Python int to binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string), I would like to know a pythonic way to get the IEEE-754 binary32 representation of a number of int, float, or double.

For example, 42.0 is to be converted to 1 10000100 01010 000000000000000000

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16444778/6464041

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import struct

getBin = lambda x: x > 0 and str(bin(x))[2:] or "-" + str(bin(x))[3:]

def floatToBinary32(value):
    val = struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('f', value))[0]
    return getBin(val)

binstr = floatToBinary32(42.0)
print('Binary equivalent of 42.0:')
print(binstr + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any build-in solution?To convert int to binary is easy: format(42,"b"), is there anything alike?