# Binary String to Audio Conversion (Python or Java)

Tags: java, python, audio, binary

I have a string of binary. I need to convert this to a wav file. Is there any existing library to achieve that goal? If so how would I write the bytes to an audio file in preferably Java or Python, but any language works.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930271/encode-binary-to-audio-python-or-c

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [Wave_write Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave-write-objects) included with Python's standard library. You will need to [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.open) a WAV file first in `'wb'` (write only) mode, and then use the appropriate methods:

- [Wave_write.close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.close)
- [Wave_write.setnchannels(n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setnchannels)
- [Wave_write.setsampwidth(n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setsampwidth)
- [Wave_write.setframerate(n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setframerate)
- [Wave_write.setnframes(n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setnframes)
- [Wave_write.setcomptype(type, name)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setcomptype)
- [Wave_write.setparams(tuple)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setparams)
- [Wave_write.tell()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.tell)
- [Wave_write.writeframesraw(data)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.writeframesraw)
- [Wave_write.writeframes(data)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.writeframes)