# How to produce a very large number in python?

Tags: python, string, numbers, largenumber

I tried making it utilizing exponents, but the `pow()` function starts giving errors at after a certain size. I need an integer about 6 million digits long. Either that or a string of numbers works too. It can't be infinity though, because I need it for string manipulation.

Comment: Wait... 6 million digits. You probably can't even keep that in memory all at once, you'll have to use disk I/O and work in parts.

Comment: Cyber I think you can easily store 6 million characters in memory on most modern computers ...

Comment: @Cyber: it is around ~500K: `(10**1000000).bit_length() // 8`

Comment: integer arithmetics has unlimited precision in Python. It might be not the fastest way to handle large numbers but the result should be precise. Check that you have not used a float by accident.

Answer (score 3):

```
size_of_number = 6000000
s = "".join(random.choice("0123456789") for _ in xrange(size_of_number))
```

doesnt work?

Comment: `os.urandom(nbytes)` might be more efficient way to generate `nbytes` random bytes (you could [use `int.from_bytes()` to get Python `int` from  the bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162190/4279))