# Byte Level Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, byte, arrays, binaryfiles

I have designed a compression algorithm that operates on the byte level representation of a file.

I want to do the following procedure:

Read k bytes from

Run algorithm on byte array of size k outputting compressed material

Write compressed material to a new file

Repeat until file is exhausted.

How do I read the first k bytes of a file?

Furthermore I want these bytes to be in binary format. I noticed that python automatically convert bytes into string character when I use the open('filename', 'rb') method, I want to actually see the bytes in the form of (0101101) and not as an integer, string, etc...

Then I want to directly write, in this binary format, to a new file.

Comment: How you "see" the bytes is not relevant to what data they contain.  If you open a file in binary mode you can read bytes from it and do as you please with them.

Comment: i think this post covers most of what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I noticed that python automatically convert bytes into string character when I use the open('filename', 'rb') method

It is incorrect. `open('filename', 'rb').read(k)` returns upto `k` bytes from the file. The value is a `bytes` object. You can print it in the binary ("01") format. See [Convert Binary to ASCII and vice versa (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279).

You can write the read `bytes` object to a new file as is:

```
open('output', 'wb').write(bytes_object)
```

There is no conversion of any kind (no `'\n'` -> `'\r\n'`, no decoding/encoding using a character encoding -- nothing).