# Big Binary Code into File in Python

Tags: python, file, binary

I have been working on a program and I have been trying to convert a big binary file (As a string) and pack it into a file. I have tried for days to make such thing possible. Here is the code I had written to pack the large binary string.

```
binaryRecieved="11001010101....(Shortened)"
f=open(fileName,'wb')
m=long(binaryRecieved,2)
struct.pack('i',m)
f.write(struct.pack('i',m))
f.close()
quit()
```

I am left with the error

```
struct.pack('i',x)
struct.error: integer out of range for 'i' format code
```

My integer is out of range, so I was wondering if there is a different way of going about with this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `m` instead of `x`? In that case `long` is too much for something that only supports an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `struct.pack` you have used 'i' which represents an integer number, which is limited. As your code states, you have a long output; thus, you may want to use 'd' in stead of 'i', to pack your data up as double. It should work.


See [Python struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) for more information.

Comment: While doubles are (almost) unilimited in how large the numbers may be, they can represent only integers up to 56bit exacly.

Comment: +jahbrohl Do you have an alternative?

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Convert your bit string to a byte string: see for example this question [Converting bits to bytes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370991/converting-bits-to-bytes-in-python). Then pack the bytes with `struct.pack('c', bytestring)`

Answer (score 1):

For encoding m in big-endian order (like "ten" being written as "10" in normal decimal use) use:

```
def as_big_endian_bytes(i):
    out=bytearray()
    while i:
        out.append(i&0xff)
        i=i>>8
    out.reverse()
    return out
```

For encoding `m` in little-endian order (like "ten" being written as "01" in normal decimal use) use:

```
def as_little_endian_bytes(i):
    out=bytearray()
    while i:
        out.append(i&0xff)
        i=i>>8
    return out
```

both functions work on numbers - like you do in your question - so the returned bytearray may be shorter than expected (because for numbers leading zeroes do not matter).

For an exact representation of a binary-digit-string (which is only possible if its length is dividable by 8) you would have to do:

```
def as_bytes(s):
    assert len(s)%8==0
    out=bytearray()
    for i in range(0,len(s)-8,8):
        out.append(int(s[i:i+8],2))
    return out
```