# Binary to Ascii

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a binary string into ASCII. The string contains 588 token {0, 1}.
I've tried it with binascii: https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html
Or like this: [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa-python)

Sample-Code:

```
sentence ="0b0101010101..."
n = int(sentence, 2)
print (n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode())
```

Output:

```
Error: print (n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Edit: this is now my solution any ideas to optimize the code?

```
 sentence ="0b0101010101..."
 length=(int(len(sentence)/8)*8)+2
 n = int(sentence[:length:1], 2)
 print (n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode("utf_8", "ignore"))
```

SOLVED!

Comment: You don't have ASCII input if you have a 0x87 byte in there. Are you 100% certain the value can be divvied up into bytes every 8 bits?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html

Comment: Can you provide us with the actual value here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Python 3, and they have a *binary* value in a string. The `binascii` module is not going to help there.

Comment: Is the binary value Unicode, and he wants it in ASCII?  What the hell?

Comment: 588 bits is *not a multiple of 8*. You have 4 bits too many or are 4 bits short. It is a multiple of 7 though, and ASCII only requires 7 bits...

Comment: Okay, this method only works if the string is divisible by 8 and if it contains only "utf-8" signs. Code works: n = int(sentence[:578:1], 2)

Is there an option to ignore other signs if they are not in "utf-8" and to cut the string automatically. I tried a only converter there it worked fine with no changes on the string(len=588, signs which are not in "utf-8": http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter

Comment: @the_new_one: So what is contained in those last 10 bits? Where does the value come from? You can tell `bytes.decode()` to use a different error handler, sure, but perhaps you can avoid those bits in the first place.

Comment: The last 10 bits are wrong values: "111111111111" the ASCII values for this is "�" and python can't handle with that. Is there a chance to put the whole string as input and to avoid the error message? If I don't know if the binary is a correct ASCII value, I will always get an error and it doesn't care if there are correct ASCII values in it. Look at the start post @Edit.