# How to Convert Binary String to Byte-like Object in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, base64

I have this line in my program: `TextV = base64.b64decode('0cQ+bNsObaw=')` and the value of `TextV` is `b'\xd1\xc4>l\xdb\x0em\xac'`. Then I run this to convert TextV to binary:

```
TextVBin = ''.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(TextV))
```

and the value of `TextVBin` is `'11010001110001001111101101100110110111110110110110101100'`. Now, I wanna again convert TextVBin format to TextV format(i.e. `b'\xd1\xc4>l\xdb\x0em\xac'`) But I googled and I couldn't find any answer. How can I do this in Python 3?

Comment: [Maybe you're looking for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675679/convert-binary-string-to-bytearray-in-pytho)?

Comment: So the question I linked to solved your problem? If so, I'll mark this a dup target.

Comment: No, I don't get the output that I want, I get this: b'\xd1\xc4\xfbf\xdfm\xac' that is different with b'\xd1\xc4>l\xdb\x0em\xac'

Comment: So how did you solve your problem?

Comment: if you did steps `A->B->C` then now you have to do `C->B->A`. first you have to split text, then convert to bytearray, etc.

Comment: I know this and this is trivial! But I don't get the desired output @furas

Comment: then show your code and we will see what is the problem. We will not write all code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your format string truncates leading zeros. You should use

```
TextVBin = ''.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in bytearray(TextV))
```

which will format each byte with exactly 8 binary digits. Then, to reverse, simply do

```
TextV = bytearray([int(TextVBin[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(TextVBin), 8)])
```

For example:

```
>>> import base64
>>> TextV = base64.b64decode('0cQ+bNsObaw=')
>>> TextV
b'\xd1\xc4>l\xdb\x0em\xac'
>>> TextVBin = ''.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in bytearray(TextV))
>>> TextVBin
'1101000111000100001111100110110011011011000011100110110110101100'
>>> TextV = bytearray([int(TextVBin[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(TextVBin), 8)])
>>> TextV
bytearray(b'\xd1\xc4>l\xdb\x0em\xac')
```

Comment: How can I remove bytearray from this?i.e, just return b'\xd1\xc4>l\xdb\x0em\xac'

Comment: On Python 3, use the `bytes` constructor instead of `bytearray`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
import struct
TextVBin = "{:b}".format(struct.unpack(">Q", TextV)[0])
```

to convert your `TextV` to binary string.

It however produces `1101000111000100001111100110110011011011000011100110110110101100` which is different than your own output, but I guess that is because leading 0 are truncated for each byte with your own method. So your method is wrong.

using struct: `1101000111000100001111100110110011011011000011100110110110101100`

using yours:
`1101000111000100  111110 110110011011011    1110 110110110101100`

Then to convert this binary string back to bytes:

```
int('1101000111000100001111100110110011011011000011100110110110101100', 2).to_bytes(8, 'big')
```

Note: I assumed that your TextVBin is 8 bytes long and big endian based on your example. If length is variable, my answer does not apply.

Comment: Can I use struct.unpack for 16 bytes object? It seems this is just for 8 bytes object