# How do I sha256 raw bits in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

```
h = '''0011001010000101011111010000101111111111101000001001000001001010110100010101111001001011000100111100011110001001111011110111011010010100110011001110111001100010111011010010101101010011110100100110101111110001100101011001000110100010000110110001100101110001'''

a = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(bytes(h,'utf-8')).digest()).decode()

>>> a
44f6dafa3d7a1720b5ebbf2adc1663df4dab03776eed48d2cda775237a547e59
```

So I have a string which represents some binary data. After writing the code above, I realised that this method was outputting the sha256 of the ascii of the string. I instead want it to output the sha256 of the raw bits similar to:

```
$ echo 0011001010000101011111010000101111111111101000001001000001001010110100010101111001001011000100111100011110001001111011110111011010010100110011001110111001100010111011010010101101010011110100100110101111110001100101011001000110100010000110110001100101110001 | shasum -a 256 -0
```

So the sha256 should be

```
>>> a
f3f06d74b794b20645460aa0b17d4e7a77eaaea283ee55344adbfcece4a63432
```

Every way I've tried it gives me errors, and I can't seem to find the answer online.

Anyone know how it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import binascii
import hashlib
s = '''0011001010000101011111010000101111111111101000001001000001001010110100010101111001001011000100111100011110001001111011110111011010010100110011001110111001100010111011010010101101010011110100100110101111110001100101011001000110100010000110110001100101110001'''
h=int(s, 2).to_bytes((len(s) + 7) // 8, byteorder='big')
a = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(h).digest()).decode()
```

Output:

```
'f3f06d74b794b20645460aa0b17d4e7a77eaaea283ee55344adbfcece4a63432'
```

[[int.to_bytes]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675679/convert-binary-string-to-bytearray-in-python-3)[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)  Return an array of bytes representing an integer.
If byteorder is `"big"`, the most significant byte is at the beginning of the byte array. If byteorder is `"little"`, the most significant byte is at the end of the byte array.

[hash.digest()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest) and `hash.hexdigest()` are similar except the digest is returned as a string object of double length, containing only hexadecimal digits in the latter case

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.