# Python Ascii to bin conversion issue

Tags: python

i'm using this line to convert Ascii string into binary string:

```
message=(''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in message))
```

Characters are converted in a 7-bit format (c --> 1100011)
Numbers are converted in a 6-bit format    (2 --> 110010) 
I need numbers converted in a 7-bit format (Adding a 0 as MSB, maybe so 2 is 0110010), any idea?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa-python. You can always add a 0 if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case your input is a string, this

```
format(ord('2'),'07b')
```

always produces a 7-bit output, e.g.

```
'0110010'
```

If you ignore the type of the input in advance (i.e. string or integer)

```
format(ord(n) if isinstance(n, str) else n,'07b')
```

for `n = '2'` produces

```
'0110010'
```

whereas for `n = 2` it produces

```
'0000010'
```

the difference lies in the fact that '2' is a string, and the representation of '2' has the value 50 (decimal)

In case you want a unique binary code for both chars and numbers (for example giving numbers the same code as chars)

```
format(ord(n) if isinstance(n, str) else n+ord('0'),'07b')
```

which now produces

```
'0110010'
```

for both `n = '2'` and `n = 2`

Does it make sense? :)

Comment: Thank you. This is the line i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
message=(''.join('0'+format(ord(x), 'b') for x in message))
```

Comment: I need both char and numbers in a 7-digit format. Using this line any char will be 8-bit