# How to write strings "0" and "1" to a file using bits

Tags: python-2.7

If I have the strings "0" and "1" how can I write them in a file in a way that each character only takes one bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to write single bits to a file, as far as I know, but you may be able to write bytes using [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bytearray). Also, representing strings is different than representing integers, are you sure you want a string?

Comment: I have to implement Huffmman compresion code, and in order to compress the file I need that each character only takes a bit.

Comment: You can only represent 2 characters using a bit, a bit's only possible values are 0 or 1. So you definitely can't represent very interesting characters as bits.

Comment: that's what I want, know how to write characters "0" and "1" using only one bit in a text.

Comment: @victor a side note: the above mentioned `bytearray` module is capable of en- and de-coding huffman codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert bits to 8-bit strings (bits are padded with zeros to form the full bytes if necessary):

```
>>> bits = "1000001"
>>> int2bytes(int(bits, 2))
'A'
```

If the number of bits is divisible by 8 then each `"0"`, `"1"` in the input is converted to exactly one bit in the result. Otherwise, each input bit requires `((n + 7) // 8) * 8 / (1.*n)` bits per bit (only slightly more than 1 for large `n`) e.g., if the number of bits `n=1001` then the ratio is ~`1.007`.

Leading zeros are forgotten. You can preserve them if you always prepend `"1"` to bits while saving and removing it while loading the bits back.

To save bits to a file:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as file: # open in binary mode
    file.write(int2bytes(int(bits, 2)))
```

where `int2bytes()`:

```
import binascii

def int2bytes(i):
    hex_string = '%x' % i
    n = len(hex_string)
    return binascii.unhexlify(hex_string.zfill(n + (n & 1)))
```

To do the reverse, see [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)