# creating binary file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary

I'm attempting to create a binary file from a python script using Python 2.7. Whenever I try converting my strings into a binary string and print it to see if it converted, it just shows the (ascii) string. Is that because print will always show the ascii equivalent and not the binary even if it is binary encoded?

EX.

```
my_string = "Testing binary string conversion"
bin_string = str.encode(my_string, "UTF-8")
print bin_string
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see here?

Comment: What is `my_file`? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **my_file is a typo, I meant my_string

I was expecting to see a binary string (0100010101, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible
>   characters, or code points, in Unicode.
>   The encoding is variable-length and uses 8-bit code units. It was
>   designed for backward compatibility with ASCII, and to avoid the
>   complications of endianness and byte order marks in the alternative
>   UTF-16 and UTF-32 encodings. The name is derived from: Universal Coded
>   Character Set + Transformation Format—8-bit.

From [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). And this explains why you see the same thing printed (because the unicode version is the same!), even `repr` should give you the same result.

To convert your string to binary you can refer to this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7397689/1938395) by Sebastian few years ago.

Hope this answer clears your doubts...

Answer (score 0):

```
import binascii


text = "Testing binary string conversion"
byte = text.encode()
hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
decimal = int(hexadecimal, 16)
binary = bin(decimal)[2:].zfill(8)
print("hex: %s, decimal: %s, binary: %s" % (hexadecimal, decimal, binary))
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?