# Binary to ASCII in Python

Tags: python, binary, ascii

I'm trying to decode binary which are located in a .txt file, but I'm stuck. I don't see any possibilities this can go around.

```
def code(): testestest
  ascii = {'01000001':'A', ...}
  binary = {'A':'01000001', ...}
  print (ascii, binary)

  def encode():
    pass

  def decode(code,n):
    f = open(code, mode='rb') # Open a file with filename <code>
    while True:
      chunk = f.read(n)           # Read n characters at time from an open file
      if chunk == '':             # This is one way to check for the End Of File in Python 
        break
      if chunk != '\n':
        # Process it????
        pass
```

How can I take the binary in the .txt file and output it as ASCII?

Comment: Oh, yeah :-) I'm sorry.
Is there any easy way the binary from the .txt file be outputted to ASCII?

Comment: What's your input? What's the expected output? This sound more easy than you're making it look.

Comment: Your answer is [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7397689/5756174). Just modify it according to your need.

Comment: Is it duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/1566267: `n = int('0b110100001100101011011000110110001101111', 2)`

Comment: can't you use `int("01000001', 2)` to convert into integer and then `chr(65)` to get char ?

Comment: You can convert between binary, ascii, and strings using [**`bin`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin), [**`int`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), and [**`chr`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr).

Comment: It makes it more complicated when it should convert the binary from a .txt, instead of clear binary in the code. I'm sorry, but I'm a total noob in python, but I love the language and would love to know this as a base for further programming.

Comment: Your comments don't make much sense. *What* makes *what* more complicated and *how*? Honestly, the link that both jblixr and John_West gave you solve your problem. You just have to read in the whole binary string in one go and feed it into that function. What exactly are you struggling with in regards to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your example, your input looks like a string of a binary formatted number.

If so, you don't need a dictionnary for that:

```
def byte_to_char(input):
     return chr(int(input, base=2))
```

---

Using the data you gave in the comments, you have to split your binary string into bytes.

```
input ='01010100011010000110100101110011001000000110100101110011001000000110101001110101011100110111010000100000011000010010000001110100011001010111001101110100001000000011000100110000001110100011000100110000'
length = 8
input_l = [input[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(input),length)]
```

And then, per byte, you convert it into a char:

```
input_c = [chr(int(c,base=2)) for c in input_l]
print ''.join(input_c)
```

Putting it all together:

```
def string_decode(input, length=8):
    input_l = [input[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(input),length)]
    return ''.join([chr(int(c,base=2)) for c in input_l])

decode(input)
>'This is just a test 10:10'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think there need to be a dictionary for holding the mapping between binary string and ascii chars? This is the binary:
 
01010100011010000110100101110011001000000110100101110011001000000110101001110101011100110111010000100000011000010010000001110100011001010111001101110100001000000011000100110000001110100011000100110000

Comment: Is that a question? No, you don't need it. you convert your binary string into an integer and then convert that integer into ascii.

Comment: Thanks, but the binary string is in an external file in a folder as mentioned.

Comment: So?
 just load that string.

Comment: So in it will be...
def code():
bin = int('0b110100001100101011011000110110001101111', 2)
pass

Comment: and...

def decode(input):
return chr(int(input, base=2))
pass

Comment: that don't work for me..do you have a quick solution for this please? I'm a total noobie:)

Comment: No, you've got to split your data into chars, each chunk of 8 bits is one byte, each byte is a char.

Comment: Yeah, that makes me confused. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was just translating one byte into a char. But I guess now it's all clear?

Comment: Thanks for your time and the code. But again, this doesnt get the binary number from an external .txt file, which it should do. Much appreciated @tglaria :)

Comment: I can't get that part for you, I don't know the format of your file. Any answer would be guessing/assuming something, and I'd rather not. your shouldn't have any problem once you've loaded the file and get the info as a string. (I would assume that if the data is text, then you don't need to do any conversion).

Comment: The line `print '.join(input_c)'` is wrong. It should be `print ''.join(input_c)`.