# Python: converting byte file to a readable ascii file

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to decode a binary file so that I can get a better look at how it's created. I'm trying to read it in using `open(file, 'rb')` and then write the converted text to `.txt` file. I can't seem to find a method that writes the text out in a format that I can understand. Are all binary converted the same way?

```
import os

def read(inputFile, outputFile):
    
    if os.path.exists(outputFile):
        os.remove(outputFile) 
    o = open(outputFile, "a")

    with open(inputFile, "rb") as i:
        while (byte := i.read(1)):
            #mapped = map(ord, byte)
            o.write(str(byte))

read('triangle.shp', 'test.txt')
```

Here is the [triangle.shp](https://github.com/samgermain/create-lfo-from-mod-wheel/blob/master/triangle.shp) file that I am trying to convert. I think that it was created using C

The output file looks like this

```js
b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\xe0'b'\xff'b'\xff'b'\xdf'b'?'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'h'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'@'b'x'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'n'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'n'b'@'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x02'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'b'\x00'
```

---

This is what I was told about the file

> Its a somewhat basic file format if you're OK with these things, its a
> little messy in value ranges and mixed data types, but it's somewhat
> simple (headerless etc).

```
typedef struct Shape_Saving_type
    {
        double val_curve[64];
        double val_EnvX[64];
        double val_EnvY[64];
        double reserved[64];
        char CurrentNumPoints;
        unsigned char Shapeversion;  //well, good for 255 versions ;)
        char padding[6]; //padding[0] set to 1 indicates LFOTOol 1.5 (vector) sizes
              
    }Chunk_Shape_Saving;
```

> You should fill with these values:
>
> val_curve[] = 0 to 1
>
> val_EnvX[] = 0 to 388.0 range
>
> val_EnvY[] = 0 to 240.0 range
>
> reserved[] fill with 0.0
>
> CurrentNumPoints is self explanatory
>
> Shapeversion = 1;
>
> padding[] fill with 0.0

Comment: For a binary file that looks completely reasonable.  It doesn't appear to be a text file created with some bizarre encoding.  You'll need to get more information on how the file was created.

Comment: If the file was purely a string encoded into binary, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557335/binary-to-string-text-in-python. But as Mark said you need more info.

Comment: All files are binary, even if their name ends with `.txt`.

Comment: @MarkRansom  I added all I know about the file so far

Comment: @Keivan I added all I know about the file so far

Comment: I was hoping with the .shp extension it might be a [Shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_(.shp)) but based on the information you added it appears it isn't.

Comment: @MarkRansom It is not, it's a custom file to the software I'm using apparently. The software is [serum](https://xferrecords.com/products/serum)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt while that may technically be true, there's a useful distinction that can be made.

Comment: So I assume that the file is made from serialization of the structure. Depending on how the serialization is done, it is not easy to convert it to text. For example some libraries like boost save the vector length with the vector. So the first byte is always the vector length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to deal with converting binary information.  For example to read the `val_curve` values:

```
import struct
bin = input_file.read(64*8)  # doubles are each 8 bytes
val_curve = struct.unpack('64d', bin)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to look at the individual values, I'm trying to look at the whole file so that I have an example for how to create one of these files myself, which I'm starting to think might involve creating a struct using that module, and then converting that struct to binary

Comment: @Sam well your question definitely says you're trying to read the file and write out a text version of it.  Once you've done that it should be relatively easy to reverse the process for writing your binary file.

Comment: I meant that it looks like you’re only reading one variable, whereas I would like to read the whole file exactly the way it is structured

Comment: @Sam doesn't my answer give you enough information to figure that out on your own?