# Python Binary string to ASCII text

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, ascii

```
x = "01100001"
```

How do i convert this string into ASCII

Expected Result:

```
print(x.somefunction())
Output: a
```

Comment: Did you googled for it? There's already a perfectly good answer on top of my google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following one liner

```
x = chr(int('010101010',2))
```

will work.