# How to save binary data in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, binary, huffman-code

I have trouble with saving binary data to the file. 
For example, I am reading data from `test.txt`:

```
this is test of Huffman algorithm
```

When I 'compress' that I got binary:

```
101010111110001101111000110101010000001011101000111011000101100111110111001110011011011100011011000100110001001011111010101011100100
```

How to save it to the file like a binary? Because if I save like a string - file size equals to 132*8 cause that's UTF-8. 
All bytes methods work badly because they translate binary to bytes.

Comment: Binary to ASCII (and vice versa) has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa

Comment: That method converts all 0 and 1 like string, so a size of result would be 1105 bytes...

Comment: What is that you're trying to accomplish, exactly? If you save a string in a file, it is in "binary" format, ie. just zero's and ones. Each character is represented by 8-bits, forming one byte (UTF-8 especially, even though ASCII is still "officially" 7-bits it's transmitted as 8-bits with it's high bit not set). If you want a human readable binary expression (which is also a valid Python expression) you can use bit().