# how can i send a byte in python via serial port?

Tags: python-3.x

When sending information via serial port using the pyserial import, the "write" function is sending the data coded as ASCII.

I would like a method to send the hex data as it is, meaning that for h"7" 
 to send "00000111" for example and not the "00110111" ascii coded.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend casting the data you're writing to the serial buffer.

See this answer: [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa)