# converting binary to text python

Tags: python, binary

I used this line of code to turn text into binary and I can't seem to find a way to take the binary from this and turn it back to text.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in contents)
```

Comment: Can you show your input, and desired output?

Comment: Hello world                                                                                           1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa

Comment: Then, Id like to be able to take the output and convert it back to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in Python 3.6:

```
b = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in contents)    
''.join([chr(int(bc, 2)) for bc in b.split(' ')])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's your problem, works for me:

```
out = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in "Hello world")
print(out)

1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100
```

If you are asking for how to revert:

```
revert = ''.join([chr(int(s, 2)) for s in out.split()])
print(revert)

Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

for python 3 this code is working

```
    binstr = '00100110 00010010'
    s = []
    for i in binstr.split(' '):
        s.append(chr(int(i)))
    print(''.join(s))
```