# How to translate a stream of '0' and '1' to characters?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to translate a stream of `0`, `1` to characters, 
without using other libraries,

for example 'Hello World':

> 0100100001000101010011000100110001001111001000000101011101001111010100100100110001000100

I found something like this:

```
def BinaryToString(binary):
    bingen = (binary[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(binary), 7))
    return ''.join(chr(eval('0b'+n)) for n in bingen)
```

but when I'm trying to translate, this is the answer:

```
>>> BinaryToString("0100100001000101010011000100110001001111001000000101011101001111010100100100110001000100")
"$\x11)Db<@W'TID\x04"
>>>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the image with text.

Comment: It is converting Binary to ASCII, then String. Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa

Comment: Thank you Kelvin, but i forgot to mention without other libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is taking 7 binary digits at a time and converting them to a character. Change it to convert 8 digits at a time.

```
def BinaryToString(binary):
    bingen = (binary[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(binary), 8))
    return ''.join(chr(eval('0b'+n)) for n in bingen)
```

This all depends on how your original text is encoded to begin with, but it works with the example you provided. (ASCII was originally defined using 7 bits. The extended ASCII table uses 8.)

Comment: Don't use `eval`. `int("1") == 1` and `int("0") == 0`; that's all you need.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that is probably slower than it needs to be. You can replace `eval('0b'+n)` with `int('0b'+n, 2)` and it works the same (in Python 3).

Comment: You don't need the `0b` prefix if you use `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`int` takes a second argument to specify the base, so you can just use something like `int("00001110", 2)` to get 14.

```
>>> binary = "0100100001000101010011000100110001001111001000000101011101001111010100100100110001000100"
>>> ''.join([chr(int(binary[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0, len(binary), 8)])
'HELLO WORLD'
```