# Python 3.8 - Convert String to Binary using binascii.a2b_uu

Tags: python, string, binary

I trying to convert string to Binary and I think I'm not making the proper use of binascii. Bellow is my code:

```
import binascii
name = 'Bruno'
for c in name:
    print ("The Binary value of '" + c +"' is", binascii.a2b_uu(c))
```

The result is not what I expected, as you can see below:

```
The Binary value of 'B' is b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
The Binary value of 'r' is b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
The Binary value of 'u' is b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
The Binary value of 'n' is b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
The Binary value of 'o' is b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What do I need to change to get the binary value in 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're looking for is a paintbrush, `binascii` is a sledgehammer. This
is just completely not the tool for what you're trying to do. You can get the
code point of a character using the `ord` function, and there are every so many
ways of converting an integer to binary. Here's one way to go about it:

```
def ascii_name(name):
    for c in name:
        print("The binary value of {} is {:08b}".format(c, ord(c)))

ascii_name("Bruno")
```

with output

```
The binary value of B is 01000010
The binary value of r is 01110010
The binary value of u is 01110101
The binary value of n is 01101110
The binary value of o is 01101111
```

See [this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa)
for more detail, and some other approaches. Some of these approaches *do* use
binascii, although unless you're being forced to use binascii I would again urge
you not to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fit the bill.